# Getting international characters from a web page?

Tags: python, html, parsing, unicode

I want to scrape some information off a football (soccer) web page using simple python regexp's.  The problem is that players such as the first chap, ÄÄRITALO, comes out as &#196;&#196;RITALO!
That is, html uses escaped markup for the special characters, such as &#196;

Is there a simple way of reading the html into the correct python string? If it was XML/XHTML it would be easy, the parser would do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would recommend [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) for HTML scraping. You also need to tell it to convert HTML entities to the corresponding Unicode characters, like so:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup    
>>> html = "<html>&#196;&#196;RITALO!</html>"
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
>>> print soup.contents[0].string
ÄÄRITALO!
```

(It would be nice if the standard [codecs](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-codecs.html) module included a codec for this, such that you could do   `"some_string".decode('html_entities')` but unfortunately it doesn't!)

**EDIT:**
Another solution:
Python developer Fredrik Lundh (author of elementtree, among other things) has  [a function to unsecape HTML entities](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-codecs.html) on his website, which works with decimal, hex and named entities (BeautifulSoup will not work with the hex ones).

Answer (score 2):

Try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).  It should do the trick and give you a nicely formatted DOM to work with as well.

[This blog](http://channel3b.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/how-to-convert-html-entities-to-real-unicode-in-python/) entry seems to have had some success with it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it myself, but have you tried

http://zesty.ca/python/scrape.html ?

It seems to have a method htmldecode(text) which would do what you want.