# How do I perform HTML decoding/encoding using Python/Django?

Tags: python, django, html-encode

I have a string that is HTML encoded:

```
'''&lt;img class=&quot;size-medium wp-image-113&quot;\
 style=&quot;margin-left: 15px;&quot; title=&quot;su1&quot;\
 src=&quot;http://blah.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/su1-300x194.jpg&quot;\
 alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;194&quot; /&gt;'''
```

I want to change that to:

```html
<img class="size-medium wp-image-113" style="margin-left: 15px;" 
  title="su1" src="http://blah.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/su1-300x194.jpg" 
  alt="" width="300" height="194" />
```

I want this to register as HTML so that it is rendered as an image by the browser instead of being displayed as text.

The string is stored like that because I am using a web-scraping tool called [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), it "scans" a web-page and gets certain content from it, then returns the string in that format.

I've found how to do this in **C#** but not in **Python**. Can someone help me out?

#### Related

- [Convert XML/HTML Entities into Unicode String in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Given the Django use case, there are two answers to this.  Here is its `django.utils.html.escape` function, for reference:

```
def escape(html):
    """Returns the given HTML with ampersands, quotes and carets encoded."""
    return mark_safe(force_unicode(html).replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&l
t;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&#39;'))
```

To reverse this, the Cheetah function described in Jake's answer should work, but is missing the single-quote.  This version includes an updated tuple, with the order of replacement reversed to avoid symmetric problems:

```
def html_decode(s):
    """
    Returns the ASCII decoded version of the given HTML string. This does
    NOT remove normal HTML tags like <p>.
    """
    htmlCodes = (
            ("'", '&#39;'),
            ('"', '&quot;'),
            ('>', '&gt;'),
            ('<', '&lt;'),
            ('&', '&amp;')
        )
    for code in htmlCodes:
        s = s.replace(code[1], code[0])
    return s

unescaped = html_decode(my_string)
```

This, however, is not a general solution; it is only appropriate for strings encoded with `django.utils.html.escape`.  More generally, it is a good idea to stick with the standard library:

```
# Python 2.x:
import HTMLParser
html_parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
unescaped = html_parser.unescape(my_string)

# Python 3.x:
import html.parser
html_parser = html.parser.HTMLParser()
unescaped = html_parser.unescape(my_string)

# >= Python 3.5:
from html import unescape
unescaped = unescape(my_string)
```

As a suggestion: it may make more sense to store the HTML unescaped in your database.  It'd be worth looking into getting unescaped results back from BeautifulSoup if possible, and avoiding this process altogether.

With Django, escaping only occurs during template rendering; so to prevent escaping you just tell the templating engine not to escape your string.  To do that, use one of these options in your template:

```
{{ context_var|safe }}
{% autoescape off %}
    {{ context_var }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: Why not use Django or Cheetah?

Comment: Is there no opposite of django.utils.html.escape?

Comment: I think escaping only occurs in Django during template rendering.  Therefore, there's no need for an unescape - you just tell the templating engine not to escape.  either {{ context_var|safe }} or {% autoescape off %}{{ context_var }}{% endautoescape %}

Comment: @Daniel: Please change your comment to an answer so that I can vote it up!  |safe was exactly what I (and I'm sure others) was looking for in answer to this question.

Comment: Should be '&#39;' instead of '&#39;/'.

Comment: I found that in django 1.3.x I didn't get my single quotes escaped.

Comment: `html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape()` is deprecated in 3.5.  Use `html.unescape()` instead.

Comment: A good option to get back the string to its previous state. thank youu

Answer (score 172):

With the standard library:

- HTML Escape

  ```
  try:
      from html import escape  # python 3.x
  except ImportError:
      from cgi import escape  # python 2.x

  print(escape("<"))
  ```
- HTML Unescape

  ```
  try:
      from html import unescape  # python 3.4+
  except ImportError:
      try:
          from html.parser import HTMLParser  # python 3.x (<3.4)
      except ImportError:
          from HTMLParser import HTMLParser  # python 2.x
      unescape = HTMLParser().unescape

  print(unescape("&gt;"))
  ```

Comment: I think this is the most straightforward, 'battery included' and correct answer. I don't know why people vote those Django/Cheetah thing.

Comment: I think so too, except that this answer doesn't seem to be complete. ``HTMLParser`` needs to be subclassed, told what to do with all the parts of any object it is fed, and then fed the object to be parsed, as seen [here](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html). Also, you will still want to use the ``name2codepoint`` dict to convert each html identity to the actual char it represents.

Comment: You're right. The unsubclassed `HTMLParser` couldn't work as we wished if we put a HTML entity into it. Maybe I should rename `htmlparser` to `_htmlparser` in order to hide it, and only expose the `unescape` method to be just like a helper function.

Comment: A note for year 2015, HTMLParser.unescape is deprecated in py 3.4 and removed in 3.5. use `from html import unescape` instead

Comment: @KarolisRyselis The answer has been updated. Thank you!

Comment: Note that this doesn't handle special characters like German Umlauts ("Ü")

Comment: @576i Can you be more specific? Unescaping works for me with Python2+3.

Answer (score 81):

For html encoding, there's **cgi.escape** from the standard library:

```
>> help(cgi.escape)
cgi.escape = escape(s, quote=None)
    Replace special characters "&", "<" and ">" to HTML-safe sequences.
    If the optional flag quote is true, the quotation mark character (")
    is also translated.
```

For html decoding, I use the following:

```
import re
from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint
# for some reason, python 2.5.2 doesn't have this one (apostrophe)
name2codepoint['#39'] = 39

def unescape(s):
    "unescape HTML code refs; c.f. http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml"
    return re.sub('&(%s);' % '|'.join(name2codepoint),
              lambda m: unichr(name2codepoint[m.group(1)]), s)
```

For anything more complicated, I use BeautifulSoup.

Comment: From the Python docs: "Deprecated since version 3.2: This function is unsafe because quote is false by default, and therefore deprecated. Use html.escape() instead." As of 3.9 and probably earlier, it's gone.

Answer (score 20):

Use daniel's solution if the set of encoded characters is relatively restricted.
Otherwise, use one of the numerous HTML-parsing libraries.

I like BeautifulSoup because it can handle malformed XML/HTML :

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

for your question, there's an example in their [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
BeautifulStoneSoup("Sacr&eacute; bl&#101;u!", 
                   convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).contents[0]
# u'Sacr\xe9 bleu!'
```

Comment: BeautifulSoup doesn't convert hex entities (&#x65;) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python/57745#57745

Comment: For BeautifulSoup4, the equivalent would be: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`
`BeautifulSoup("Sacr&eacute; bl&#101;u!").contents[0]`

Answer (score 17):

In Python 3.4+:

```
import html

html.unescape(your_string)
```

Comment: U saved my day. I was looking for that answer for hours. I saved texts with German umlauts to a file and had to convert them back somehow.
It works like a charm.

import html
html.unescape('Klima&#228;nderungen')
'Klimaänderungen'

Comment: Jianngge Zhang had already given this answer in 2011.

Answer (score 7):

See at the bottom of this [page at Python wiki](http://wiki.python.org/moin/EscapingHtml), there are at least 2 options to "unescape" html.

Answer (score 7):

If anyone is looking for a simple way to do this via the django templates, you can always use filters like this:

```
<html>
{{ node.description|safe }}
</html>
```

I had some data coming from a vendor and everything I posted had html tags actually written on the rendered page as if you were looking at the source.

Comment: Thank you, God. this solution apply to Flask!!!

Answer (score 6):

Daniel's comment as an answer:

"escaping only occurs in Django during template rendering. Therefore, there's no need for an unescape - you just tell the templating engine not to escape. either {{ context_var|safe }} or {% autoescape off %}{{ context_var }}{% endautoescape %}"

Comment: Works, except that my version of Django does not have 'safe'. I use 'escape' instead. I assume it's the same thing.

Comment: @willem: they're the opposite!

Answer (score 5):

I found a fine function at: http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/4569

```
def decodeHtmlentities(string):
    import re
    entity_re = re.compile("&(#?)(\d{1,5}|\w{1,8});")

    def substitute_entity(match):
        from htmlentitydefs import name2codepoint as n2cp
        ent = match.group(2)
        if match.group(1) == "#":
            return unichr(int(ent))
        else:
            cp = n2cp.get(ent)

            if cp:
                return unichr(cp)
            else:
                return match.group()

    return entity_re.subn(substitute_entity, string)[0]
```

Comment: The benefit of using re is you can match both &#039; and &#39; using the same search.

Comment: This doesn't handle `&#xA0;` which should decode to the same thing as `&#160;` and `&nbsp;`.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is a really old question, this may work.

Django 1.5.5

```
In [1]: from django.utils.text import unescape_entities
In [2]: unescape_entities('&lt;img class=&quot;size-medium wp-image-113&quot; style=&quot;margin-left: 15px;&quot; title=&quot;su1&quot; src=&quot;http://blah.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/su1-300x194.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;194&quot; /&gt;')
Out[2]: u'<img class="size-medium wp-image-113" style="margin-left: 15px;" title="su1" src="http://blah.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/su1-300x194.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="194" />'
```

Comment: This was the only one that was able to decode surrogate pairs encoded as html entities, like `"&#55349;&#56996;"`.  Then after another `result.encode('utf-16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf-16')`, I finally had the original back.

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Cheetah source code ([here](http://www.koders.com/python/fid549827F97513858275EEA43DC0135AC97AEAEF57.aspx))

```
htmlCodes = [
    ['&', '&amp;'],
    ['<', '&lt;'],
    ['>', '&gt;'],
    ['"', '&quot;'],
]
htmlCodesReversed = htmlCodes[:]
htmlCodesReversed.reverse()
def htmlDecode(s, codes=htmlCodesReversed):
    """ Returns the ASCII decoded version of the given HTML string. This does
        NOT remove normal HTML tags like <p>. It is the inverse of htmlEncode()."""
    for code in codes:
        s = s.replace(code[1], code[0])
    return s
```

not sure why they reverse the list,
 I think it has to do with the way they encode, so with you it may not need to be reversed.
Also if I were you I would change htmlCodes to be a list of tuples rather than a list of lists...
this is going in my library though :)

i noticed your title asked for encode too, so here is Cheetah's encode function.

```
def htmlEncode(s, codes=htmlCodes):
    """ Returns the HTML encoded version of the given string. This is useful to
        display a plain ASCII text string on a web page."""
    for code in codes:
        s = s.replace(code[0], code[1])
    return s
```

Comment: The list is reversed because decode and encode replacements always have to be made symmetrically. Without the reversing you could eg. convert '& amp;lt;' to '& lt;', then in the next step incorrectly convert that to '<'.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use django.utils.html.escape

```
from django.utils.html import escape

something_nice = escape(request.POST['something_naughty'])
```

Comment: OP asked about unescaping, not escaping.

Comment: In the title itsellf he also asked for encoding - just found your answer and am grateful for it.

Comment: Not what the OP asked, but I found this useful.

Answer (score 1):

This is the easiest solution for this problem -

```
{% autoescape on %}
   {{ body }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

From [this page](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs).

Answer (score 0):

Below is a python function that uses module `htmlentitydefs`.  It is not perfect.  The version of `htmlentitydefs` that I have is incomplete and it assumes that all entities decode to one codepoint which is wrong for entities like `&NotEqualTilde;`:

http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/named-character-references.html

> ```
> NotEqualTilde;     U+02242 U+00338    ≂̸
> ```

With those caveats though, here's the code.

```
def decodeHtmlText(html):
    """
    Given a string of HTML that would parse to a single text node,
    return the text value of that node.
    """
    # Fast path for common case.
    if html.find("&") < 0: return html
    return re.sub(
        '&(?:#(?:x([0-9A-Fa-f]+)|([0-9]+))|([a-zA-Z0-9]+));',
        _decode_html_entity,
        html)

def _decode_html_entity(match):
    """
    Regex replacer that expects hex digits in group 1, or
    decimal digits in group 2, or a named entity in group 3.
    """
    hex_digits = match.group(1)  # '&#10;' -> unichr(10)
    if hex_digits: return unichr(int(hex_digits, 16))
    decimal_digits = match.group(2)  # '&#x10;' -> unichr(0x10)
    if decimal_digits: return unichr(int(decimal_digits, 10))
    name = match.group(3)  # name is 'lt' when '&lt;' was matched.
    if name:
        decoding = (htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint.get(name)
            # Treat &GT; like &gt;.
            # This is wrong for &Gt; and &Lt; which HTML5 adopted from MathML.
            # If htmlentitydefs included mappings for those entities,
            # then this code will magically work.
            or htmlentitydefs.name2codepoint.get(name.lower()))
        if decoding is not None: return unichr(decoding)
    return match.group(0)  # Treat "&noSuchEntity;" as "&noSuchEntity;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Searching the simplest solution of this question in Django and Python I found you can use builtin theirs functions to escape/unescape html code.

## Example

I saved your html code in `scraped_html` and `clean_html`:

```
scraped_html = (
    '&lt;img class=&quot;size-medium wp-image-113&quot; '
    'style=&quot;margin-left: 15px;&quot; title=&quot;su1&quot; '
    'src=&quot;http://blah.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/su1-300x194.jpg&quot; '
    'alt=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;300&quot; height=&quot;194&quot; /&gt;'
)
clean_html = (
    '<img class="size-medium wp-image-113" style="margin-left: 15px;" '
    'title="su1" src="http://blah.org/wp-content/uploads/2008/10/su1-300x194.jpg" '
    'alt="" width="300" height="194" />'
)
```

## Django

*You need Django >= 1.0*

### unescape

To unescape your scraped html code you can use [django.utils.text.unescape_entities](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/2.0.x/django/utils/text.py#L377) which:

> Convert all named and numeric character references to the corresponding unicode characters.

```
>>> from django.utils.text import unescape_entities
>>> clean_html == unescape_entities(scraped_html)
True
```

### escape

To escape your clean html code you can use [django.utils.html.escape](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.html.escape) which:

> Returns the given text with ampersands, quotes and angle brackets encoded for use in HTML.

```
>>> from django.utils.html import escape
>>> scraped_html == escape(clean_html)
True
```

## Python

*You need Python >= 3.4*

### unescape

To unescape your scraped html code you can use [html.unescape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) which:

> Convert all named and numeric character references (e.g. `&gt;`, `&#62;`, `&x3e;`) in the string s to the corresponding unicode characters.

```
>>> from html import unescape
>>> clean_html == unescape(scraped_html)
True
```

### escape

To escape your clean html code you can use [html.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.escape) which:

> Convert the characters `&`, `<` and `>` in string s to HTML-safe sequences.

```
>>> from html import escape
>>> scraped_html == escape(clean_html)
True
```