# Decoding html encoded strings in python

Tags: python, html, xml

I have the following string...

```
"Scam, hoax, or the real deal, he&#8217;s gonna work his way to the bottom of the sordid tale, and hopefully end up with an arcade game in the process."
```

I need to turn it into this string...

> Scam, hoax, or the real deal,
>   he’s gonna work his way to the
>   bottom of the sordid tale, and
>   hopefully end up with an arcade game
>   in the process.

This is pretty standard HTML encoding and I can't for the life of me figure out how to convert it in python.

I found this:
[GitHub](http://github.com/sku/python-twitter-ircbot/blob/321d94e0e40d0acc92f5bf57d126b57369da70de/html_decode.py)

And it's very close to working, however it does not output an apostrophe but instead some off unicode character.

Here is an example of the output from the GitHub script...

> Scam, hoax, or the real deal, heâs
>   gonna work his way to the bottom of
>   the sordid tale, and hopefully end up
>   with an arcade game in the process.

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's you're trying to do is called "HTML entity decoding" and it's covered in a number of past Stack Overflow questions, for example:

- [How to unescape apostrophes and such in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/816272/how-to-unescape-apostrophes-and-such-in-python)
- [Decoding HTML Entities With Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/628332/decoding-html-entities-with-python)

Here's a code snippet using the [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) HTML parsing library to decode your example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

string = "Scam, hoax, or the real deal, he&#8217;s gonna work his way to the bottom of the sordid tale, and hopefully end up with an arcade game in the process."
s = BeautifulSoup(string,convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES).contents[0]
print s
```

Here's the output:

> Scam, hoax, or the real deal, he’s
>   gonna work his way to the bottom of
>   the sordid tale, and hopefully end up
>   with an arcade game in the process.

Comment: I had tried the BeautifulSoup code earlier and was still getting an exception.  Turns out it was somewhere else in my code having trouble using the decoded Unicode characters.