# Escaping HTML in Python

Tags: python, html, escaping

How to escape HTML with characters like `&#8211;` in Python?

Comment: See this previous Stack Overflow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913933/decoding-html-encoded-strings-in-python

Comment: Not to be confused with "Escaping FROM Pythons!"

Comment: @Alex, please clarify: do you have a Python Unicode string and want to produce the escaped HTML, or viceversa, do you have the HTML containing escapes and want to produce a Python Unicode string?

Comment: @Alex, I'd like to produce a Python Unicode string from HTML with escapes ASCII string, well, and the other way round as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a unicode string as input, you can use the xmlcharrefreplace error handler:

```
py> u"<p>\N{EN DASH}</p>".encode("ascii", "xmlcharrefreplace")
'<p>&#8211;</p>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
import cgi
print cgi.escape("<b>Your HTML Bold Text</b>")
```