# Is is possible to html encode output in AppEngine templates?

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, html-encode

So, I'm passing an object with a "content" property that contains html.

```
<div>{{ myobject.content }}</div>
```

I want to be able to output the content so that the characters are rendered as the html characters.

The contents of "conent" might be: <p>Hello</p>

I want this to be sent to the browser as: &lt;p&gt;Hello&lt;/p&gt;

Is there something I can put in my template to do this automatically?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `{{ myobject.content | escape }}` should help (assuming you mean Django templates -- there's no specific "App Engine" templating system, GAE apps often use the Django templating system); you may need to repeat the `| escape` part if you want two levels of escaping (as appears to be the case in some but not all of the example you supply).

Comment: My small app is using Google's webapp framework. But I think that framework does default to using the Django template system.

Answer (score 2):

This is Django's django.utils.html.escape function:

```
def escape(html):
    """Returns the given HTML with ampersands, quotes and carets encoded."""
    return mark_safe(force_unicode(html).replace('&', '&amp;').replace('<', '&l
t;').replace('>', '&gt;').replace('"', '&quot;').replace("'", '&#39;'))
```

Also, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django).