# String with double quotes inside input value in python

Tags: python, double-quotes

I want to display a string in input value. That string contain double quotes. I want to display it as it is. Its developed with Python

```
<input  id="answer" name="answer" type="text"  value="<%= element.answer %>" />
```

My string content is `Testing "quotes" test`

When its displayed in input field, it shows only Testing because of double quotes issue.

I have tried `escape(element.answer)` to display it. But it shows this result

```
Testing%20%22quotes%22%20test
```

I want to display the exact content. Pllease help

Comment: which templating language are you using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Escape html in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3096948/escape-html-in-python)

Comment: @olly_uk: Its Backbone.js

Answer (score 1):

Thanks. Got solution for this problem

Instead of this `<%= element.answer %>`

I have changed it to `<%- element.answer %>`

It works fine now