# Including HTML variable in Django template without escaping

Tags: python, html, django, encoding

I have html encoded text which reads like this:

```
RT <a href="http://twitter.com/freuter">@freuter</a>...
```

I want this displayed as html but I am not sure if there is a filter which i can apply to this text to convert the html-encoded text back to html ...

can someone help?

Answer (score 28):

As Daniel says, use the `{{ tweet|safe }}` filter in the html, or mark it safe from the views.

Use `django.template.mark_safe()`

Comment: But first check if the content is really safe. I would not blindly trust tweets directly from twitter's api for example.

Answer (score 4):

Try the |safe filter if you want to render all HTML.

Answer (score 2):

See: [How do I perform HTML decoding/encoding using Python/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django)

I think this answers your querstion.