# Simple Django question: how to allow html as output from a variable?

Tags: django

this template variable `{{object.video.description}}` is outputing this text:

```
Welcome to <a href="http://google.com">Saint Francis Academy</a> in the heart of Washington.
```

How can I get the link to show as an actual link instead of being replaced with html entities. I tried filtering it as safe but no luck: `{{object.video.description|safe}}`

Answer (score 3):

Can you go to the django shell and see what text is recorded in object.video.description?

How/where does video.description get defined as an html string (what I'm guessing is that a `<` is already be escaped into `&lt;` at that point and hence safe won't help).  Marking as safe prevents django from converting `<` to `&lt;` right before rendering in the template; but won't convert a string containing `&lt;` into a `<`.

If the string is originally saved with `&lt;`s and `&gt`s you can convert them to `<` and `>` by a simple python replacement somewhere in your string processing.   E.g., in your view do something like:

```
htmlCodes = (('&', '&amp;'),
             ('<', '&lt;'),
             ('>', '&gt;'),
             ('"', '&quot;'),
             ("'", '&#39;'),)

def unescape(some_html_str):
    for c, html_code in htmlCodes:
        some_html_str = some_html_str.replace(html_code, c)
    return some_html_str
```

and then remember to unescape your string in your view before putting it in the context (and still remember to mark it safe).
See [How do I perform HTML decoding/encoding using Python/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django)

Also it may be better/easier for you to use `mark_safe` (`from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe`) in your views to make sure only safe strings are marked safe rather than have your template always render something safe.

Answer (score 1):

```
{% load markup %}
{{ object.video.description|markdown }}
```

Comment: This assumes that video.description is written in markdown: e.g., a link to wikipedia's markdown pages is `[some_text](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown)`.  Now if users are writing text descriptions, its a very good idea to use a markup language https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/markup/ (rather than letting users write raw html where they could insert javascript for say a CSRF attack or javascript pop-ups or whatever).

Comment: sorry, yea my answer should be qualified with that what dr jimbob said!