# double encoded html code

Tags: python, postgresql, wysiwyg, html-content-extraction

I use xinha as WYSIWYG editor for html-content.
I sent html-articles via post-form to postgresql.
So far so good, they seem ok.
But when I receive and output from pg to an html page, I see double encoded, i.e. broken html code 
like this

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;google.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;   &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;   &lt;p&gt;
```

Any idea on where to search for the issue?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You should probably post some code to explain how you're getting the data in and out of postgres.

Comment: How about a more specific breakdown of the process? You're not providing a whole lot to go on.

Comment: Seems similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django)

Answer (score 2):

```
import HTMLParser
hp=HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
s="&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;&gt;google.com&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;   &lt;p&gt; &lt;/p&gt;   &lt;p&gt;"
print hp.unescape(s)

# u'<p><a href="http://google.com">google.com</a></p>   <p> </p>   <p>'
```