# Re to replace & with name entity

Tags: python, regex

I have to replace `&` with its name entity or decimal entity from input string, but input string may contains other name and decimal entities in with `&` will present.

**Code**:

```
import re
text =' At&T, " < I am > , At&T  so  &#60; &lt; &  & '

#- Get all name entities and decimal entities.
replace_tmp = re.findall("&#\d+;|&[a-z]+;", text)

#- Replace above values from tempvalues.
tmp_dict = {}
count = 1
for i in replace_tmp:
    text = text.replace(i, "$%d$"%count)
    tmp_dict["$%d$"%count] = i
    count += 1


#- Replace & with &amp;
text = text.replace("&", "&amp;")

#- Replace tempvalues values with original.
for i in tmp_dict:
    text = text.replace(i, tmp_dict[i])

print text
```

**Final Output**: `At&amp;T, " < I am > , At&amp;T so &#60; &lt; &amp; &amp;`

**But Can I get regular expression which directly does above thing?**

---

**Final line in py file**:

`value = re.sub(r'&(?!(#[0-9]+;|[a-zA-Z]+;))', '&amp;', value).replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;").replace('"', "&quot;")`

Comment: What is the output you expect?

Comment: expected output: `At&amp;T, " < I am > , At&amp;T  so  &#60; &lt; &amp;  &amp; `

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I perform HTML decoding/encoding using Python/Django?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django)

Comment: See particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7088472/1084416)

Comment: @VivekSable use negative lookahead as indicated in my answer, its better to use predefined function though

Comment: What about escaping the `<` and `>`? i.e. `&lt;` and `&gt;`.

Comment: @PeterWood i think OP doesn't need that (as shown in his Final Output text)

Comment: no, I am getting correct output from above code, I am looking if there is re method which replace  `&` with `&amp;` in one or two lines

Comment: This string we put in attribute value of tag. We can directly replace `<` , '>` and `"` with its name entities..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'&(?!(#[0-9]+;|\w+;))', '&amp;', ' At&T, " < I am > , At&T  so  &#60; &lt; &  & ')
' At&amp;T, " < I am > , At&amp;T  so  &#60; &lt; &amp;  &amp; '
```

You can use negative look ahead assertion for `\w+;` (for eg: `&nbsp;`) and `#[0-9]+;` (for `#60;`).

Therefore the regex is:

`&(?!(#[0-9]+;|\w+;))`
negative look ahead assertion ensures there is neither `#[0-9]+;` nor `\w+;` ahead of `&`

You could also use `[a-zA-Z]+;` instead of `\w+;`

Comment: Thanx, looking to same.

Comment: `re.sub(r'&(?!(#[0-9]+;|[a-zA-Z]+;))', '&amp;', '''& At&T, " < I am &>& , At&T  "so"  &#60; &lt; &  & ''').replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;").replace('"', "&quot;")` this is my final py line

Answer (score 1):

Use string substitution with negative look ahead.

```
import re
text =' At&T, " < I am > , At&T  so  &#60; &lt; &  & '

text = re.sub(r'&(?![\w\d#]+?;)',"&amp;",text)
print text
```

Comment: `&` can be any where, this is only one test case