# Why pytesseract raise an error with Arabic language

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I want to use pytesseract Arabic And I have ara.traineddata in my system /usr/share/tesseract/tessdata/ path and i have already installed tesseract package

This is my code:

```
 import pytesseract
 from PIL import Image
 pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test_arabic.png'), config='', lang="ara")
```

and i get this error:

```
TesseractError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
```

in

```
----> 1 pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('test_persian.png'), config='', lang="ara")

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in image_to_string(image, lang, config, nice, output_type, timeout)
    368     args = [image, 'txt', lang, config, nice, timeout]
    369 
--> 370     return {
    371         Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
    372         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in <lambda>()
    371         Output.BYTES: lambda: run_and_get_output(*(args + [True])),
    372         Output.DICT: lambda: {'text': run_and_get_output(*args)},
--> 373         Output.STRING: lambda: run_and_get_output(*args),
    374     }[output_type]()
    375 

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_and_get_output(image, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout, return_bytes)
    280         }
    281 
--> 282         run_tesseract(**kwargs)
    283         filename = kwargs['output_filename_base'] + extsep + extension
    284         with open(filename, 'rb') as output_file:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pytesseract/pytesseract.py in run_tesseract(input_filename, output_filename_base, extension, lang, config, nice, timeout)
    256     with timeout_manager(proc, timeout) as error_string:
    257         if proc.returncode:
--> 258             raise TesseractError(proc.returncode, get_errors(error_string))
    259 
    260 

TesseractError: (1, 'read_params_file: parameter not found:')
```

---

Thanks for help.

Comment: AFAIU you should run with lang='ara', but this is not the cause of the problem. Can you run the same come throught command line ?

Comment: that was a mistake

 i runned with lang='ara'






and in command line i run this(tesseract --lang ara test_arabic.png text.txt
) and i get this: read_params_file: parameter not found: �PNG

Comment: Hey Anybody? 
I really need a help

Comment: did you try to give a full path of your image when you open it?

Comment: Yes Path is ok.

Comment: @benjamin Can you please provide the test image to form the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the proper language model and the latest version:

#### For Windows 10:

[tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200328.exe](https://digi.bib.uni-mannheim.de/tesseract/tesseract-ocr-w64-setup-v5.0.0-alpha.20200328.exe) (64 bit) resp.

To validate installation in the power shell or cmd terminal execute:

`tesseract -v`

It will output something like this: tesseract v5.0.0-alpha.20200328

#### For Mac OS:

`brew install tesseract`

To validate installation in the power shell or cmd terminal execute:

`tesseract -v`

It will output something like this: tesseract 4.1.1 and also the installed image libraries
leptonica-1.80.0
libgif 5.2.1 : libjpeg 9d : libpng 1.6.37 : libtiff 4.1.0 : zlib 1.2.11 : libwebp 1.1.0 : libopenjp2 2.3.1
Found AVX2
Found AVX
Found FMA
Found SSE

If you are not sure about the path, then simply copy paste the [ara.traindata](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tessdata/raw/4.00/ara.traineddata) file in the same folder as that of your Python .py file

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
import os
os.environ["TESSDATA_PREFIX"] = "" # Leaving it empty because file is already copy pasted in the current directory
print(os.getenv("TESSDATA_PREFIX"))
# Copy paste the ara.traineddata file in the same directory as this python code
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('cropped.png'), lang="ara"))
```

#### For Linux/Ubuntu OS:

`sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr`

The validation and run code is same as that of Mac Os

Also make sure the path is fine.

This code works fine if the ara.traineddata file is downloaded successfully:

```py
import pytesseract
from PIL import Image
print(pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('cropped.png'), lang="ara"))
```

You can follow this [tutorial](https://youtu.be/lGeM3lSdwRM) for details. Here is the demo output of this tutorial which uses Arabic language as well.

[image]