# How to show rendered template as raw source code block?

Tags: html, django, templates, raw

I want to provide a rendered HTML block that shows an email signature - what it looks like with user data from the context - and also displays the populated HTML code as raw src to be copied for pasting into customers email signature. What would be the best (dry) way to do this?

I have tried render_to_string as a variable in the context but the HTML is rendered.

Comment: Your question is difficult to understand, please add some of your html so people may understand what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by following this answer:

[How do I perform HTML decoding/encoding using Python/Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/275174/how-do-i-perform-html-decoding-encoding-using-python-django)

The rendered django template HTML needs to be decoded before it can be shown in the pre tag otherwise it will be marked up by the browser.