# Replace html entities with the corresponding utf-8 characters in Python 2.6

Tags: python, html-entities, python-2.6

I have a html text like this:

```
&lt;xml ... &gt;
```

and I want to convert it to something readable:

```
<xml ...>
```

Any easy (and fast) way to do it in Python?

Comment: I think the question is a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: Best approach here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2360598/how-do-i-unescape-html-entities-in-a-string-in-python-3-1

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Python >= 3.4

Official documentation for `HTMLParser`: [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape)

```
>>> from html import unescape
>>> unescape('&copy; &euro;')
© €
```

### Python < 3.5

Official documentation for `HTMLParser`: [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

```
>>> from html.parser import HTMLParser
>>> pars = HTMLParser()
>>> pars.unescape('&copy; &euro;')
© €
```

Note: this was deprecated in the favor of `html.unescape()`.

### Python 2.7

Official documentation for `HTMLParser`: [Python 2.7](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/htmlparser.html)

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> pars = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> pars.unescape('&copy; &euro;')
u'\xa9 \u20ac'
>>> print _
© €
```

Comment: unescape is just an internal function of HTMLParser (and it's not documented in your link). however I could use the implementation.

10x a lot

Comment: @brtzsnr: true, that it's undocumented. Don't think that it's internal though, after all name is unescape not _unescape or __unescape.

Answer (score 3):

Modern Python 3 approach:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('&copy; &euro;')
© €
```

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html

Answer (score 1):

There is a function [here](http://effbot.org/zone/re-sub.htm#unescape-html) that does it, as linked from the post Fred pointed out.  Copied here to make things easier.

Credit to Fred Larson for linking to the other question on SO.
Credit to dF for posting the link.