# Decode HTML entities in Python string?

Tags: python, html, html-entities

I'm parsing some HTML with Beautiful Soup 3, but it contains HTML entities which Beautiful Soup 3 doesn't automatically decode for me:

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

>>> soup = BeautifulSoup("<p>&pound;682m</p>")
>>> text = soup.find("p").string

>>> print text
&pound;682m
```

How can I decode the HTML entities in `text` to get `"£682m"` instead of `"&pound;682m"`.

Comment: related: [Convert XML/HTML Entities into Unicode String in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/57708/convert-xml-html-entities-into-unicode-string-in-python)

Answer (score 723, accepted):

#### Python 3.4+

Use [`html.unescape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&pound;682m'))
```

FYI `html.parser.HTMLParser.unescape` is deprecated, and [was supposed to be removed in 3.5](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.5/Lib/html/parser.py#L466-L470), although it was left in by mistake. It will be removed from the language soon.

---

#### Python 2.6-3.3

You can use `HTMLParser.unescape()` from the standard library:

- For Python 2.6-2.7 it's in [`HTMLParser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html)
- For Python 3 it's in [`html.parser`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

```
>>> try:
...     # Python 2.6-2.7 
...     from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
... except ImportError:
...     # Python 3
...     from html.parser import HTMLParser
... 
>>> h = HTMLParser()
>>> print(h.unescape('&pound;682m'))
£682m
```

You can also use the [`six`](https://pythonhosted.org/six/) compatibility library to simplify the import:

```
>>> from six.moves.html_parser import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser()
>>> print(h.unescape('&pound;682m'))
£682m
```

Comment: this method doesn't seem to escape characters like "&#8217;" on google app engine, though it works locally on python2.6. It does still decode entities (like &quot;) at least

Comment: How can an undocumented API be deprecated? Edited the answer.

Comment: @MarkusUnterwaditzer there's no reason that an undocumented method can't be deprecated. This one throws deprecation warnings - see my edit to the answer.

Comment: It would seem more logical that, rather than just the `unescape` method, the entire `HTMLParser` module were deprecated in favor of `html.parser`.

Comment: Worth noting for Python 2: Special characters are replaced with their Latin-1 (ISO-8859-1) encoding counterparts. E.g., it may be necessary to `h.unescape(s).encode("utf-8")`. The docs:  """The definition provided here contains all the entities defined by XHTML 1.0 that can be handled using simple textual substitution in the Latin-1 character set (ISO-8859-1)"""

Comment: It does not work for 'Don&‌#039;t forget that &‌pi; = 3.14 &‌amp; doesn&‌#039;t equal 3.' WHY is that?

Comment: @canbax Those work for me. `html.unescape('Don&#039;t forget that &pi; = 3.14 &amp; doesn&#039;t equal 3.')` produces `"Don't forget that π = 3.14 & doesn't equal 3."` for me on Python 3.11.3

Answer (score 72):

Beautiful Soup handles entity conversion. In Beautiful Soup 3, you'll need to specify the `convertEntities` argument to the `BeautifulSoup` constructor (see the ['Entity Conversion'](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html#Entity%20Conversion) section of the archived docs). In Beautiful Soup 4, entities get decoded automatically.

#### Beautiful Soup 3

```
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup("<p>&pound;682m</p>", 
...               convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)
<p>£682m</p>
```

#### Beautiful Soup 4

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> BeautifulSoup("<p>&pound;682m</p>")
<html><body><p>£682m</p></body></html>
```

Comment: +1. No idea how I missed this in the docs: thanks for the info.  I'm going to accept luc's answer tho because his uses the standard lib which I specified in the question (not important to me) and its probably of more general use to other people.

Comment: `BeautifulSoup4` uses `HTMLParser`, mostly. See the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/builder/_htmlparser.py)

Comment: How do we get the conversion in Beautiful Soup 4 without all the extraneous HTML that wasn't part of the original string? (i.e. <html> and <body>)

Comment: @Praxiteles : BeautifulSoup('&pound;682m', "html.parser") https://stackoverflow.com/a/14822344/4376342

Answer (score 16):

You can use replace_entities from w3lib.html library

```
In [202]: from w3lib.html import replace_entities

In [203]: replace_entities("&pound;682m")
Out[203]: u'\xa3682m'

In [204]: print replace_entities("&pound;682m")
£682m
```

Answer (score 8):

Beautiful Soup 4 allows you to [set a formatter to your output](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)

> If you pass in `formatter=None`, Beautiful Soup will not modify strings
>   at all on output. This is the fastest option, but it may lead to
>   Beautiful Soup generating invalid HTML/XML, as in these examples:

```
print(soup.prettify(formatter=None))
# <html>
#  <body>
#   <p>
#    Il a dit <<Sacré bleu!>>
#   </p>
#  </body>
# </html>

link_soup = BeautifulSoup('<a href="http://example.com/?foo=val1&bar=val2">A link</a>')
print(link_soup.a.encode(formatter=None))
# <a href="http://example.com/?foo=val1&bar=val2">A link</a>
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. (Also, I have no idea what the docs are saying is invalid about the final bit of HTML here.)

Comment: <<Sacré bleu!>> is the invalid part, as it has unescaped < and > and will break the html around it.  I know this is a late post from me, but in case anyone happens to be looking and wondered...

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar encoding issue. I used the normalize() method. I was getting a Unicode error using the pandas .to_html() method when exporting my data frame to an .html file in another directory. I ended up doing this and it worked...

```
    import unicodedata
```

The dataframe object can be whatever you like, let's call it table...

```
    table = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['Name','Team','OVR / POT'])
    table.index+= 1
```

encode table data so that we can export it to out .html file in templates folder(this can be whatever location you wish :))

```
     #this is where the magic happens
     html_data=unicodedata.normalize('NFKD',table.to_html()).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

export normalized string to html file

```
    file = open("templates/home.html","w") 

    file.write(html_data) 

    file.close()
```

Reference: [unicodedata documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/unicodedata.html)

Comment: This does not answer the question. A Unicode normalization form is not the same as HTML entities.

Answer (score 0):

```
import html
  
myHtml = "<body><h1> How to use html.unescape() in Python </h1></body>"
encodedHtml = html.escape(myHtml)
print("Encoded HTML: ", encodedHtml)
decodedHtml = html.unescape(encodedHtml)
  
print("Decoded HTML: ", decodedHtml)
```

---

Output:

```
Encoded HTML:  &lt;body&gt;&lt;h1&gt; How to use html.unescape() in Python &lt;/h1&gt;&lt;/body&gt;
Decoded HTML:  <body><h1> How to use html.unescape() in Python </h1></body>
```

---

[Demo](https://ideone.com/5vR36z)

Answer (score -5):

This probably isnt relevant here.  But to eliminate these html entites from an entire document, you can do something like this:  (Assume document = page and please forgive the sloppy code, but if you have ideas as to how to make it better, Im all ears - Im new to this).

```
import re
import HTMLParser

regexp = "&.+?;" 
list_of_html = re.findall(regexp, page) #finds all html entites in page
for e in list_of_html:
    h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
    unescaped = h.unescape(e) #finds the unescaped value of the html entity
    page = page.replace(e, unescaped) #replaces html entity with unescaped value
```

Comment: No! You don't need to match HTML entities yourself and loop over them; `.unescape()` does that *for you*. I don't understand why you and Rob have posted these overcomplicated solutions that roll their own entity matching when the accepted answer already clearly shows that `.unescape()` can find entities in the string.