# How to deal with utf-8 encoded String and BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I replace HTML-entities in unicode-Strings with proper unicode?

```
u'&quot;HAUS Kleider&quot; - &Uuml;ber das Bekleiden und Entkleiden, das Verh&Yuml;llen und Veredeln'
```

to

```
u'"HAUS-Kleider" - Über das Bekleiden und Entkleiden, das Verhüllen und Veredeln'
```

**edit**
Actually the entities are wrong. At it seems like BeautifulSoup f...ed it up.

So the question is: **How to deal with utf-8 encoded String and BeautifulSoup?**

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

f = open('path_to_file','r')
lines = [i for i in f.readlines()]
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(lines))
allArticles = []
for row in rows:
    l =[]
    for r in row.findAll('td'):
            l += [r.string] # here things seem to go wrong
    allArticles+=[l]
```

`Ü -> &Yuml;` instead of `&Uuml;` but actually I don't want the encoding to be changed anyway.

```
>>> soup.originalEncoding
'utf-8'
```

but I cant generate a proper unicode string of it

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: Things seem to go wrong? BeautifulSoup f'ed it up? The entities are wrong? Please try to give more precise details to make this question answerable. BeautifulSoup tends to handle UTF-8 pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem was silly, I have to confess. I was working on an old version of `rows` in the interactive interpreter. I don't know what was wrong with it contents, but this is the correct code:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

f = open('path_to_file','r')
lines = [i for i in f.readlines()]
soup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(lines))
rows = soup.findAll('tr')
allArticles = []
for row in rows:
    l =[]
    for r in row.findAll('td'):
        l += [r.string]
    allArticles+=[l]
```

shame on me!

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need are [ICU transliterators](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit). I think there is a way to *transliterate* HTML entities into Unicode.

Try the *transliterator id* `Hex/XML-Any` that should to what you want. On the Demo page you can choose "Insert Sample: Compound" and then enter `Hex/XML-Any` into the "Compound 1" box, add some input data in the box and press "transform". Does [this](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/translit?TEMPLATE_FILE=data/translit_template.html&ARG_INPUT=enter-your-text-here&COMPOUND_ID1=Hex/XML-Any) help?

There is a Python ICU binding, but its not taken care of well, I think.

Answer (score 1):

`htmlentitydefs.entitydefs["quot"]` returns
`'"'`
That's a dictionary that translates entities to their actual character.
 You should be able to continue easily from that point.

Comment: if BeautifulSoup would give me the right entities at all. see my edit