# Parsing malformed string in python

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

I have a malformed string in Python:

```
Muhammad Ali&#39;s fight with Larry Holmes
```

where `&#39;` is a apostrophe.

Firstly what representation is this: `&#39;`? Secondly, how can I parse the string in python so that it replaces `&#39;` with `'`

Comment: This looks like a HTML entity of a character with code 39 (which would make it easy to parse and reassemble using `chr()`. However there are is also a big number of symbolic HTML entities like `&amp;` (`&`) which you'd probably want to also consider.

Comment: @All: I did not know how to search for an answer because I did not know what to search.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Python Standard Library's [`HTMLParser`](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) is able to decode HTML entities in strings.

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> s = h.unescape('&copy; 2010')
>>> s
u'\xa9 2010'
>>> print s
© 2010
>>> s = h.unescape('&#169; 2010')
>>> s
u'\xa9 2010'
```

A range of solutions are described here: http://fredericiana.com/2010/10/08/decoding-html-entities-to-text-in-python/

Answer (score 1):

The `&#CHAR-CODE;` is a sytax for special chars in html (maybe elsewhere, but I'm not sure).  There may be a more complete way to do this, but you could replace it simply with:

```
mystring = "Muhammad Ali&#39;s fight with Larry Holmes"
print mystring.replace("&#39;", "'")
```

Yields:

> Muhammad Ali's fight with Larry Holmes