# how to convert ISO 8859-1 Characters to UTF-8

Tags: php, utf-8, iso

I use CURL to get content from another site, but i don't know why it's auto convert from UTF-8 to ISO 8859-1, like follow:

site: abc.com:

> Cửa Hàng Chip Chip: Rộn ràng đón Giáng sinh với những vật phẩm trang trí Noel đầy màu sắc của CHIPCHIP GIFT SHOP

But when i use CURL get content from that site, i got follow:

```
Cửa Hàng Chip Chip: Rộn r&agrave;ng đ&oacute;n Gi&aacute;ng sinh với những vật phẩm trang tr&iacute; Noel đầy m&agrave;u sắc của CHIPCHIP GIFT SHOP
```

So how to convert it's become to UTF-8 ?

Comment: Those are [character entity references](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references).

Comment: That can't be ISO-8859-1; you can't express all of those accents in that codepage. It's probably already UTF-8, just with some character entities like sarnold mentions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using `iconv`.

`iconv --list` gives you a list of all known encodings, and you can then use `iconv -f FROM_ENCODING -t TO_ENCODING` do do your conversion. It can also read from stdin and therefore be plugged to `curl`.

But regarding the comment you got for your question: It seems like the file author didn't care about using the correct encoding and decided to stick with (old-style?) `&auml` and stuff.

Comment: i try use iconv, but i always get this error 

`Notice: iconv(): Detected an illegal character in input string in D:\UniServer\www\deal\haha.php on line 5 C`

this is my code:
`echo iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1", $text);`

Comment: Sorry, partially my fault. You did not specify that you're working with PHP excpet for the php tag, so I was assuming you're working in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

Take your string in variable and use following function.

```
$var = "";
echo utf8_encode($var);
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the line you pasted, the problem appears to be with HTML entities, not with character enconding. The encoded chars look fine to me.

You need to translate those HTML entities to encoded chars. Which tool to use will depend of your enviroment or programming language. I don't think it can be done with CURL alone.

PHP has [htmlspecialchars_decode()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php). Python [unescape()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) from the HTMLParser module.

Comment: I forgot tell u, it display good for me, but when i convert it to ascii to make seo URL, i have problem with that. Example:

`Rộn ràng đón Giáng sinh => ron rang don giang sinh (true)`

My problem

`Rộn ràng đón Giáng sinh => Rộn ragraveng đoacuten Giaacuteng sinh (wrong)`

Answer (score 0):

curl does not convert anything, downloads things "as is"

What you see are character entities, valid html, and the browser that the conversion to a readable form.

You can check this by opening the file saved by curl in a browser. It will look like the live page.

Comment: Better yet: view the source of the page you’re looking at.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
html_entity_decode($string)
```

See more here: [html_entity_decode](https://doc.bccnsoft.com/docs/php-docs-7-en/function.html-entity-decode.html)

Answer (score 0):

Your files aren’t being converted to another encoding. They’re using [HTML character entities](https://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).  You need to [convert those entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25372068/convert-html-entities-and-special-characters-to-utf8-text-in-php), such as `&eacute;` to UTF-8, such as é.  This takes one extra line of code after you convert to UTF-8, if you even need to do that.