# PHP get HTML - missing characters

Tags: php, html, encoding, entities

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to convert ISO 8859-1 Characters to UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253914/how-to-convert-iso-8859-1-characters-to-utf-8)

i would like to get the HTML content of this uRL: http://www.20minutos.es/noticia/1635461/0/aforo/madrid-arena/vigilantes/

But there are missing characters (like 'ñ' or 'á', 'é'...)

The code to get the HTML is

```
$html = file_get_contents_utf8($url);
```

and then:

```
$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
```

I've tried a few alternatives but still not working.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is your internal encoding? You can just use `file_get_contents( $url );` if your encoding is utf8.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what encoding you are trying to convert to, but using file_get_contents() should do 
what you are trying to do.

Change your code as follows

```
<?php
 $url = 'http://www.20minutos.es/noticia/1635461/0/aforo/madrid-arena/vigilantes/';
 $html = file_get_contents($url);
 echo $html;
?>
```

I tested this and it shows all the characters (like 'ñ' or 'á', 'é'...) you were referring to.