# Ampersand confusion

Tags: python, unicode

Might be a silly question but for some reason & isnt recognized as &. I get text from an API and `&amp;` is printed as `&amp;` and not &. I encode via UTF8 but it doesnt catch it

Comment: please, post some code (especially the encoding part) so that we can help you :)

Comment: You have referenced HTML entity, and it is hard to say where do you "print" it, and what exactly is the result of the API call.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string

Comment: slipped my mind to check for HTML, thanks for the link @MarkRansom that solved all my problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&amp;` is the HTML escape sequence for the ampersand. It has got nothing to do with the character encoding. If you open the page you're fetching in your browser (if possible), you'll see it in the sourcecode either.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) to translate the [HTML Entity names.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp)

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulStoneSoup
BeautifulStoneSoup("&amp;",convertEntities=BeautifulStoneSoup.ALL_ENTITIES)
```