# Scrapy: extract JSON from within HTML script

Tags: python, html, json, xpath, scrapy

I'm trying to extract (what appears to be) JSON data from within an HTML script. The HTML script looks like this on the site:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var terms    = new Verba.Compare.Collections.Terms([{"id":"6436","name":"SUMMER 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true},{"id":"6517","name":"FALL 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true}]);
    var view     = new Verba.Compare.Views.CourseSelector({el: "body", terms: terms});
  });
</script>
```

I'd like to pull out the following:

```
[{"id":"6436","name":"SUMMER 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true},{"id":"6517","name":"FALL 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true}]
```

Using the following code, I'm able to get the full script.

```
    def parse(self, response):
        print response.xpath('/html/body/script[2]').extract()
```

Is there a simple way to then extract the values for "id", "name", etc. from that script. Or, is there a more direct way by modifying the xpath? I can't seem to go any deeper on the xpath using firebug.

Comment: Would this help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13323976/how-to-extract-a-json-object-that-was-defined-in-a-html-page-javascript-block-us

Answer (score 3):

You can use [js2xml](https://github.com/scrapinghub/js2xml) for this.

To illustrate, first, let's create a Scrapy selector with your sample HTML, and grab the JavaScript statements:

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> sample = '''<script>
...   $(document).ready(function(){
...     var terms    = new Verba.Compare.Collections.Terms([{"id":"6436","name":"SUMMER 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true},{"id":"6517","name":"FALL 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true}]);
...     var view     = new Verba.Compare.Views.CourseSelector({el: "body", terms: terms});
...   });
... </script>'''
>>> selector = scrapy.Selector(text=sample, type='html')
>>> selector.xpath('//script//text()').extract_first()
u'\n  $(document).ready(function(){\n    var terms    = new Verba.Compare.Collections.Terms([{"id":"6436","name":"SUMMER 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true},{"id":"6517","name":"FALL 16","inquiry":true,"ordering":true}]);\n    var view     = new Verba.Compare.Views.CourseSelector({el: "body", terms: terms});\n  });\n'
```

Then we can parse the JavaScript code with js2xml. You get an lxml tree back:

```
>>> import js2xml
>>> jssnippet = selector.xpath('//script//text()').extract_first()
>>> jstree = js2xml.parse(jssnippet)
>>> jstree
<Element program at 0x7fc7c6bae1b8>
```

What does the tree look like? It's pretty verbose:

```
>>> print(js2xml.pretty_print(jstree))
<program>
  <functioncall>
    <function>
      <dotaccessor>
        <object>
          <functioncall>
            <function>
              <identifier name="$"/>
            </function>
            <arguments>
              <identifier name="document"/>
            </arguments>
          </functioncall>
        </object>
        <property>
          <identifier name="ready"/>
        </property>
      </dotaccessor>
    </function>
    <arguments>
      <funcexpr>
        <identifier/>
        <parameters/>
        <body>
          <var name="terms">
            <new>
              <dotaccessor>
                <object>
                  <dotaccessor>
                    <object>
                      <dotaccessor>
                        <object>
                          <identifier name="Verba"/>
                        </object>
                        <property>
                          <identifier name="Compare"/>
                        </property>
                      </dotaccessor>
                    </object>
                    <property>
                      <identifier name="Collections"/>
                    </property>
                  </dotaccessor>
                </object>
                <property>
                  <identifier name="Terms"/>
                </property>
              </dotaccessor>
              <arguments>
                <array>
                  <object>
                    <property name="id">
                      <string>6436</string>
                    </property>
                    <property name="name">
                      <string>SUMMER 16</string>
                    </property>
                    <property name="inquiry">
                      <boolean>true</boolean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="ordering">
                      <boolean>true</boolean>
                    </property>
                  </object>
                  <object>
                    <property name="id">
                      <string>6517</string>
                    </property>
                    <property name="name">
                      <string>FALL 16</string>
                    </property>
                    <property name="inquiry">
                      <boolean>true</boolean>
                    </property>
                    <property name="ordering">
                      <boolean>true</boolean>
                    </property>
                  </object>
                </array>
              </arguments>
            </new>
          </var>
          <var name="view">
            <new>
              <dotaccessor>
                <object>
                  <dotaccessor>
                    <object>
                      <dotaccessor>
                        <object>
                          <identifier name="Verba"/>
                        </object>
                        <property>
                          <identifier name="Compare"/>
                        </property>
                      </dotaccessor>
                    </object>
                    <property>
                      <identifier name="Views"/>
                    </property>
                  </dotaccessor>
                </object>
                <property>
                  <identifier name="CourseSelector"/>
                </property>
              </dotaccessor>
              <arguments>
                <object>
                  <property name="el">
                    <string>body</string>
                  </property>
                  <property name="terms">
                    <identifier name="terms"/>
                  </property>
                </object>
              </arguments>
            </new>
          </var>
        </body>
      </funcexpr>
    </arguments>
  </functioncall>
</program>
```

You can use your XPath skills to point to the JavaScript array (you want the 1st argument of the "dot" accessor for the `new` contruct assigned to `var terms`):

```
>>> jstree.xpath('//var[@name="terms"]')
[<Element var at 0x7fc7c565e638>]
>>> jstree.xpath('//var[@name="terms"]/new/arguments/*')
[<Element array at 0x7fc7c565e5a8>]
>>> jstree.xpath('//var[@name="terms"]/new/arguments/*')[0]
<Element array at 0x7fc7c565e5a8>
```

Finally, now that you have the `<array>` element, you can pass it to `js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict()` to get a nice Python object to work with (`make_dict` is kinda misnamed):

```
>>> js2xml.jsonlike.make_dict(jstree.xpath('//var[@name="terms"]/new/arguments/*')[0])
[{'ordering': True, 'inquiry': True, 'id': '6436', 'name': 'SUMMER 16'}, {'ordering': True, 'inquiry': True, 'id': '6517', 'name': 'FALL 16'}]
>>>
```

Note: you can also use the shortcut `js2xml.jsonlike.getall()` to fetch everything that looks like a Python dict or list (you get 2 lists, you're interested in the 1st one):

```
>>> js2xml.jsonlike.getall(jstree)
[[{'ordering': True, 'inquiry': True, 'id': '6436', 'name': 'SUMMER 16'}, {'ordering': True, 'inquiry': True, 'id': '6517', 'name': 'FALL 16'}], {'el': 'body', 'terms': 'terms'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would extract it using a regex, something like:

```
response.xpath('/html/body/script[2]').re_first('\((\[.*\])\)')
```

Comment: It works! After a bit more research I figured out a similar method to what you just posted. However, yours is much cleaner. Thank you.

Comment: You are most welcome. Please feel free to mark this as answer, if it has solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

[chompjs](https://github.com/Nykakin/chompjs) provides an API to parse JavaScript objects into a dict.

For example, if the JavaScript code contains `var data = {field: "value", secondField: "second value"}`; you can extract that data as follows:

```
import chompjs
javascript = response.css('script::text').get()
data = chompjs.parse_js_object(javascript)
```

The final result is
`{'field': 'value', 'secondField': 'second value'}`
a

Answer (score -1):

You can't go "deeper" because that element's contents are just text. It's not too hard to read out the JSON from the JavaScript:

```
line = javascript.strip().splitlines()[1]
the_json = line.split('(', 1)[1].split(')', 1)[0]
```