# How to convert &lt; into < in lxml, Python?

Tags: python, lxml

There's a xml file:

```
<body>
    <entry>
         I go to <hw>to</hw> to school.
    </entry>
</body>
```

For some reason, I changed `<hw>` to `&lt;hw&gt;` and `</hw>` to `&lt;/hw&gt;` before parsing it with lxml parser.

```
<body>
    <entry>
         I go to &lt;hw&gt;to&lt;/hw&gt; to school.
    </entry>
</body>
```

But after modifying the parsed xml data, I want to get a `<hw>` element, not `&lt;hw&gt;`. How can I do that?

Comment: Consider this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First find a `unescape` function:

```
from xml.sax.saxutils import unescape

entry=body[0]
```

unescape and replace it with the original:

```
body.replace(entry, e.fromstring(unescape(e.tounicode(entry))))
```

Comment: `entry.text` is already unescaped. No `unescape()` is necessary

Comment: Finally I can make my code do what I need it to do and not be forced to settle for what the lxml library thinks I need. Thank you.

Comment: What is the `e` in `e.fromstring` ?

Answer (score 1):

If you know which element contains wrongly escaped elements:

```
# parse whole document as usual..
# find the entry element..
# parse the fragment
fragment = lxml.fromstring(entry.text)
# (optionally) add the fragment to the tree
entry.text = None
entry.append(fragment)
```