# django:ValueError need more than 1 value to unpack

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I'm using ajax and django for dynamically populate a combo box. ajax component works really fine and it parse the data to the view but int the view, when i'm using the spiting function  it gives me a exception called "Value Error:need more than 1 value to unpack ". can anyone helps me to figure out the error :) :)
code:

```
def dropdownPopulate(request):



if request.method=='POST' :
    key = request.POST['id']
else:
    key=""



level, tree_id=key.split(",")

next_nodes=Structure.objects.filter(tree_id=key[tree_id]).filter(level=key[level])
context={'name':next_nodes}     
return render_to_response('renderAjax.html',context)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `s.split(',')` is returning list of length `1`:

```
level, tree_id = key.split(',')
```

Make sure it return list of length `2`:

```
parts = key.split(',')
if len(parts) == 2:
    level, tree_id = parts
elif len(parts) == 1:
    level = parts[0]
    tree_id = None
else:
    # do something
    level = tree_id = None
    pass
```

The apply filter like this:

```
next_nodes = Structure.objects.all()
if level:
    next_nodes = next_nodes.filter(level=level)
if tree_id:
    next_nodes = next_nodes.filter(tree_id=tree_id)
```

Comment: the data coming from the ajax is like this [u&#39;1&#39;, u&#39;0&#39;] so i want to get the numerical values only by removing the Unicode values how can i do that ???

Answer (score 0):

Probably error occurs at this line:

```
level, tree_id=key.split(",")
```

It is needed to handle the situation, when `key` will not have `","`. Or maybe it will have more than one `","`.

Look at your code:

```
if request.method=='POST' :
    key = request.POST['id']
else:
    key=""
```

It is possible, that `key` will be a blank string.

Here are examples, when error can occur:

1.

```
>>> key = ""
>>> level, tree_id=key.split(",")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

2.

```
>>> key = "a,b,c"
>>> level, tree_id=key.split(",")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
```

Only this will be fine (when it is only one `","`):

```
>>> key = "a,b"
>>> level, tree_id=key.split(",")
>>>
```

Comment: the data coming from the ajax is like this [u&#39;1&#39;, u&#39;0&#39;] so i want to get the numerical values only by removing the Unicode values how can i do that ???

Comment: In that case you need to unescape your data: `import HTMLParser`; `h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser(`); `print h.unescape("[u&#39;1&#39;, u&#39;0&#39;]")`. The result will be `"[u'1', u'0']"`. Look [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems.

> level, tree_id=key.split(",")

This will fail, as `key` may not have `,`, so `split` will not return 2 values.

> next_nodes=Structure.objects.filter(tree_id=key[tree_id]).filter(level=key[level])

Here you are accessing `key` as dict, which is incorrect as it is string.

Comment: the data coming from the ajax is like this [u&#39;1&#39;, u&#39;0&#39;] so i want to get the numerical values only by removing the Unicode values how can i do that ???

Comment: @himanka, I think you need to fix ajax not to send values in that form. There seems values in single quotes in url encoded form.