# Encoding a string with ASCII Characters (Find and replace?)

Tags: python, encoding, flask

I have a string like below:

```
THE SMASH-HIT, CRITICALLY ACCLAIMED SERIES RETURNS! Now that you&#39;ve read the first two bestselling collections of SAGA , you&#39;re all caught up and ready to jump on the ongoing train with Chapter Thirteen, beginning an all-new monthly sci-fi/fantasy adventure, as Hazel and her parents head to the planet Quietus in search of cult romance novelist D. Oswald Heist.
```

as can be seen, the apostrophes ( ' ) are being represented as ASCII code:

```
&#39
```

how would you suggest I encode this string?

Other ascii codes are appearing as well:

```
&quot;
&amp;
```

Comment: Why do you want to encode the string? What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: Those are HTML character references. ASCII has nothing to do with your problem.

Comment: I am displaying the string on a website made with Flask. So in a browser. http://www.longboxed.com/issue/JUN130454D

Comment: The first possible dup is 3.x-specific; the second is 2.x-specific. The accepted answers are the same, except for the fact that 2.x's `HTMLParser` was renamed `html.parser` in 3.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those are called [HTML entities](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references). The easiest way is to unescape them is to use [HtmlParser](http://docs.python.org/library/htmlparser.html) from standard library:

```
>>> s = "THE SMASH-HIT, CRITICALLY ACCLAIMED SERIES RETURNS! Now that you&#39;ve read the first two bestselling collections of SAGA , you&#39;re all caught up and ready to jump on the ongoing train with Chapter Thirteen, beginning an all-new monthly sci-fi/fantasy adventure, as Hazel and her parents head to the planet Quietus in search of cult romance novelist D. Oswald Heist."
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(s)
u"THE SMASH-HIT, CRITICALLY ACCLAIMED SERIES RETURNS! Now that you've read the first two bestselling collections of SAGA , you're all caught up and ready to jump on the ongoing train with Chapter Thirteen, beginning an all-new monthly sci-fi/fantasy adventure, as Hazel and her parents head to the planet Quietus in search of cult romance novelist D. Oswald Heist."
```

Also see:

- [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: Instead of linking to a duplicate question and summarizing its answer, just close this question as a dup.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I see now that I didnt really understand my problem. Yes it was a dupe, but I think he deserves the credit anyway.

Comment: Agreed, just wanted to clarify that those things are called html entities and give a live example.