# Getting &amp; instead of & in title return using PRAW

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I'm trying to get the top 25 of all time of a given subreddit using PRAW:

```
import praw
subreddit = 'gamedeals'
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='getting top 25 of all time by /u/sqrg')
submissions = r.get_subreddit(subreddit).get_top_from_all(limit=25)
titlesFile = open("text.txt", 'w')
for s in submissions:
    titlesFile.write(s.title.encode('utf-8', 'replace') + '\n')
titlesFile.close()
```

I get the following error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa3' in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)

So I changed the line inside the for loop to:

```
titlesFile.write(s.title.encode('utf-8', 'replace') + '\n')
```

And it works, but in the text.txt file I get `&amp;` instead of `&`. I could change them with some string replace function, but is there any way to directly write the correct title? Also, why did I have to use the `encode()` method?

Comment: [Have a look in decoding html entities](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the setting to decode html entities:

```
r = praw.Reddit(user_agent='getting top 25 of all time by /u/sqrg')
r.config.decode_html_entities = True
```

Config file docs: https://praw.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/configuration_files.html

More info here: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/issues/186