# Scrape subreddit post titles and use them as filename using Praw

Tags: python, python-3.x, reddit, praw

My code currently downloads images from a given subreddit and will name them as the original file name. What I would like the code to do is to name them as what they are posted on Reddit. Would anyone be able to help me out please? I think it's something to do with Submission.title but I can't figure it out. cheers.

```
import praw
import threading
from requests import get
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import os


client_id = 'xxxxxxxxx'
client_secret = 'xxxxxxxxx'
user_agent = 'xxxxxxxxx'
image_directory = 'images'
thread_count = 16

target_subreddit = 'space'
image_count = '10'
order = 'hot'

order = order.lower()

reddit = praw.Reddit(client_id=client_id,
                     client_secret=client_secret, user_agent=user_agent)


def get_order():
    if order == 'hot':
        ready = reddit.subreddit(target_subreddit).hot(limit=None)
    elif order == 'top':
        ready = reddit.subreddit(target_subreddit).top(limit=None)
    elif order == 'new':
        ready = reddit.subreddit(target_subreddit).new(limit=None)
    return ready


def get_img(what):
    image = '{}/{}/{}'.format(image_directory,
                              target_subreddit, what.split('/')[-1])
    img = get(what).content
    with open(image, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(img)


def make_dir():
    directory = f'{image_directory}/{target_subreddit}'
    if not os.path.exists(directory):
        os.makedirs(directory)


def main():
    c = 1
    images = []
    make_dir()
    for submission in get_order():
        url = submission.url
        if url.endswith(('.jpg', '.png', '.gif', '.jpeg')):
            images.append(url)
            c += 1
            if int(image_count) < c:
                break

    results = ThreadPool(thread_count).imap_unordered(get_img, images)
    for path in results:
        pass

    print('Done')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Anyone has working version of this, that also really renames the files based on post title? I have tried for half a day without any success.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, so if your 'url' variable is giving you a correct url, then simply submission.title should give you the title. You may be getting tripped up with the encoding, so you may want to convert it with str(), or get a bit [fancier with the encode function.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19759358/getting-amp-in-title-return-using-praw) Also, some characters are not allowed in many file names, so perhaps try stripping unallowable characters from the title.