# Cannot convert HTML from a site to text properly

Tags: python, python-2.7, text, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

EDIT: I cannot believe that BeautifullSoup actually cannot parse HTML properly. Actually i maybe do something wrong, but if I do not this is a really amateurish module.

I am trying to  get text from web but i am unable to do so as i am always getting some strange characters in the most of sentences. I never get a sentence that containt words such as "isn't' correctly.

```
useragent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'}
request = urllib2.Request('SomeURL',None,useragent)
myreq = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = 5)
html = myreq.read()

#get paragraphs
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
textList = soup.find_all('p')
mytext = ""
for par in textList:
    if len(str(par))<2000: 
    print par
    mytext +=" " +  str(par)

 print "the text is ", mytext
```

The result contains some strange characters:

```
The plural of â€œcomedoâ€? is comedomesâ€?.</p>
Surprisingly, the visible black head isnâ€™t caused by dirt
```

Obviously i want to get isn't instead of isnâ€™t. What should i do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate. I first need to extract all the paragraphs. I think that the decoding deletes all the <p> tags.

Comment: I would need something to tell beautifullsoup now to ruin my html. I cannot believe that such a reputable python module cannot properly parse html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution based on people's answers from here and my research.

```
import html2text
import urllib2
import re
import nltk

useragent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'}
request = urllib2.Request('SomeURL',None,useragent)
myreq = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = 5)
html = myreq.read()
html = html.decode("utf-8")


textList = re.findall(r'(?<=<p>).*?(?=</p>)',html, re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)
mytext = ""
for par in textList:
   if len(str(par))<2000: 
    par = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', par)
    mytext +=" " +  html2text.html2text(par)

 print "the text is ", mytext
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is with your system output encoding, which cannot output the encoded character properly since it's outside the displayed character range.

BeautifulSoup4 is meant to fully support HTML entities.

Notice the strange behaviour of these commands:

```
>python temp.py
...
ed a blackhead. The plural of ÔÇ£comedoÔÇØ is comedomesÔÇØ.</p>
...

>python temp.py > temp.txt

>cat temp.txt
....
ed a blackhead. The plural of "comedo" is comedomes".</p> <p> </p> <p>Blackheads is an open and wide
....
```

I suggest writing your output to a text file, or perhaps using a different terminal/changing your terminal settings to support a wider range of characters.

Comment: I am still getting - â€œcomedoâ€? is comedomesâ€ -  Did you use python 2.7?

Comment: My python is messing up, I keep getting different outputs. Can you tell me what versions of python and beautifulsoup you have?

Comment: it is python 2.7.3 and bs4

Comment: Do you see some strange -  Â  characters as well?

Comment: I saw the characters before, but now when I try to run your code, I can't see them anymore. Still trying to figure out what's going on

Comment: Thanks for the effort.

Comment: Where are you running Python from? after testing, I believe it is a problem with your character encoding.

Comment: Windows 7. Where do i set the character encoding?

Comment: Anyway i cannot believe that after 10 hours  i am still not able to get a proper output. The best i could get if i use regex instead of BS are sentences with wrong quotes - best “medical grade facial” istead of best "medical grade facial".

Comment: I am also on Windows 7. The program runs fine on IDLE after a few tries. I can't get it to work in Command Prompt, but I can redirect the output using `>` to a text file (read edited answer), and it seems to encode fine there.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48685/discussion-between-icedtrees-and-brana)

Answer (score 0):

Since this is Python 2 the `urllib.urlopen().read()` call returns a string of bytes most likely encoded in UTF-8 - you can look at the HTTP headers to see the encoding if it is specifically included. I assumed UTF-8.

You fail to decode this external representation before you start handling the content, and this is only going to lead to tears. General rule: decode inputs immediately, encode only on output.

Here's your code in working form with only two modifications;

```
import urllib2
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

useragent = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_4) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.57 Safari/536.11'}
request = urllib2.Request('SomeURL',None,useragent)
myreq = urllib2.urlopen(request, timeout = 5)
html = unicode(myreq.read(), "UTF-8")

#get paragraphs
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
textList = soup.findAll('p')
mytext = ""
for par in textList:
    if len(str(par))<2000: 
      print par
      mytext +=" " +  str(par)

print "the text is ", mytext
```

All I have done is added unicode decoding of `html` and used `soup.findAll()` rather than `soup.find_all()`.

Comment: I tried and and I see the same. How to see http headers?

Comment: Rather odd. When I run the above code then the HTML I see contains `The plural of &#8220;comedo&#8221; is comedomes&#8221;.` - which is to say that the left and right quote marks have been correctly dealt with.

Access the headers using `myreq.headers.headers`. I didn't see much of value, but did confirm you are dealing with a UTF-8 stream. The content appears to have an opening quotation mark missing.

Comment: Yes it is charset=UTF-8 as i see. Never mind i added the solution that works for me. I use bs4 which probably does something strange.