# Replacing or unescaping &amp; doesn't work in my code in Python. Why?

Tags: python

Both work in interactive console(idle).
My source:

```
        from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
        parser = HTMLParser()
        a=autohist # autohist is a string containing source from selenium
        tags = []
        start = 0
        while a.find("alt=\\\"", start) != -1:
            find = a.find("alt=\\\"", start)+6
            print find
            titleartist = ""
            while a[find] != "\\":
                s = a[find]
                titleartist = titleartist + s
                find +=1
            start=find+1
            if titleartist=="Explicit Lyrics":
                continue
            titleartist = titleartist.replace("&amp;","shit")
            #titleartist = parser.unescape(titleartist)
            print titleartist
            tags.append((titleartist.split(" - ")[1],titleartist.split(" - ")[0]))
```

But when I get a html source using selenium Firefox
Example:

```
 titleartist="Diana Ross &amp; The Supremes"
```

it prints this:
     Diana Ross shitamp; The Supremes

Obviously I want to replace `&amp;` with `&`, but this example shows the problem.

Comment: I suspect the API gets the text values as double-encoded (¿perhaps a &amp; chunk exist beforehand instead of &?)

Comment: But how do I solve it?

Comment: like the replace() decodes &amp; to & but why?

Comment: Can you please give us an SSCCE? It's not clear what you're getting at and there's a fair amount of, erm, extraneous "shit". Pun intended. :-)

Comment: Looks like I was simplyfying too much as this works:
s="We Own It (Fast &amp; Furious)"
s = s.replace("&amp;","&")
print s

Comment: I think there's a problem with what I get from webdriver.Firefox().page_source

Comment: And there's FB login, javascript handling at shazam.com, so I think I can't make a SSCCE that would work

Comment: @LuisMasuelli Yes as when I copied the text, it worked, I think selenium.page_source gives something double-encoded. But how do I solve that?

Comment: run replace() twice xDDD. let me search a while as i look for a better solution

Comment: try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string, however you should double-decode the string (use it instead of replace())

Comment: from the solution: parser.unescape(parser.unescape(titleartist)).replace("&", "shit")

Comment: @Luis how do I double decode? .decode("dont know what").decode("dont know")

Comment: Also I quite solved it now - it's not the selenium. I replaced &amp; in the original html and that worked instead of replacing in particular titleartist

Comment: decode like this: parser.unescape(value) if you expect normally-encoded values, or parser.unescape(parser.unescape(value)) if you expect double-encoded values. `value` could be `titleartist`, for example.

Comment: @Luis thanks .replace("&amp;","&").replace("&amp;","&") WORKS

Comment: tell your solution in an answer so the question does not remain open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow that first `while` part gets it double encoded, so the solution is to decoded it twice. For example:

```
titleartist.replace("&amp;","&").replace("&amp;","&")
```