# Python RSS reader text filtering

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, filter, rss

On my quest to better learn **python 3.4**, I decided to create a 'practical' program that simply reads the RSS feed of a link you give it. I was testing using the CNN RSS feed and got the description to print, but the description also contains a lot of "crap" I don't need, is there a quick way to remove the unnecessary text? Basically I want to keep "A deal to sell the Los Angeles Clippers for an NBA record price may move forward, a California probate judge ruled Monday." and remove everything else. Thanks.

Full Rss tag:

```
<description>A deal to sell the Los Angeles Clippers for an NBA record price may move forward, a California probate judge ruled Monday.&lt;div class="feedflare"&gt;
&lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:yIl2AUoC8zA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=yIl2AUoC8zA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:7Q72WNTAKBA"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=7Q72WNTAKBA" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:V_sGLiPBpWU"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:V_sGLiPBpWU" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:qj6IDK7rITs"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?d=qj6IDK7rITs" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt; &lt;a href="http://rss.cnn.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?a=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:gIN9vFwOqvQ"&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~ff/rss/cnn_topstories?i=FMi4oVkdS58:sssPw82MBtA:gIN9vFwOqvQ" border="0"&gt;&lt;/img&gt;&lt;/a&gt;
&lt;/div&gt;&lt;img src="http://feeds.feedburner.com/~r/rss/cnn_topstories/~4/FMi4oVkdS58" height="1" width="1"/&gt;</description>
```

Comment: I think you can just delete everything between `&lt;` and `&gt;`

Comment: How do you decide which parts of the text are necessary and unnecessary? A regex like `<description>([^&]*)` would extract what you want from your current example, but may not work in all cases.

Comment: @JoYSword That is what I want to do, but how do I accomplish that? The tag I provided is given by CNN, I am parsing it and printing it out in a terminal window.

Comment: @jonrsharpe The "useless" text always starts with the text '&lt;' continues through the description tag.

Comment: Then that regex could do it - it takes all text between the opening tag and the first `'&'`. Or use a lookahead for more robust results: `<description>(.*)(?=&lt;)`. See [here](http://regex101.com/r/hT4sH2/1).

Comment: what is the feed url?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham [Here is the RSS](http://rss.cnn.com/rss/cnn_topstories.rss), you might have to do a 'CTRL-U' to see the source though.

Comment: you know there is a library to do this?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It would be helpful if you could elaborate...

Comment: @jonrsharpe if there are some html tags inside the useful part this will not succeed.`<description>Joel shuts down &lt;em&gt;stackoverflow&lt;/em&gt;&lt;[useless part]&gt;</description>`

Comment: @tanishqdubey, feedparser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Is there a quick way," you ask? Maybe.

First off, take a look at what you're really getting back by copying the entire bit of text you've given us and running it through this online HTML decoder:

http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/DotNet/Tools/HTMLEncode/Decode.aspx

That should give you an idea of what you're dealing with. You need to decode the text so that it looks like proper HTML. You'll then see that, nested inside the `description` tag, you have a `div` tag and an `img` tag following the text you're interested in. If you believe that this is *consitently* what you get back from the feed, then it's safe to capture everything before the `<div>` and toss the rest away.

Take a look at this answer, regarding decoding HTML:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/155167

Once you've decoded the HTML, you can probably just use the `find` method of `string` objects.

```
# Assume text is decoded HTML, so the <div> looks like a normal tag.
start = len('<description>')
end = text.find('<div>')
text = text[start: end]
```