# Replacing parts of strings in a list in Python

Tags: python, string, list

I know similar questions exist for this topic but I've gone through them and still couldn't get it.

My python program retrieves a subsection of html from a page using a regular expression. I just realised that I hadn't accounted for html special characters getting in the way.

say I have:

`regex_title = ['I went to the store', 'Itlt&#039;s a nice day today', 'I went home for a rest']`

I obviously want to change `lt&#039;` to a single quote '.

I've tried variations of:

```
for each in regex_title:
    if 'lt&#039;' in regex_title:
        str.replace("lt&#039;", "'")
```

but had no success. What am I missing.

NOTE: The purpose is to do this without importing any more modules.

Comment: This seems odd to me.  unescaping that html should leave you with `Itlt's`, not `It's`...

Comment: Also note that [there may be a better way](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/748858) ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`str.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) does not replace in-place. It returns the replaced string. You need to assigned back the return value.

```
>>> regex_title = ['I went to the store', 'Itlt&#039;s a nice day today',
...                'I went home for a rest']
>>> regex_title = [s.replace("lt&#039;", "'") for s in regex_title]
>>> regex_title
['I went to the store', "It's a nice day today", 'I went home for a rest']
```

Comment: Excellent. Thank you. I didn't realise I had to reassign the variable.

Answer (score 2):

If your task is to unescape HTML, then better use `unescape` function:

```
>>> ll = ['I went to the store', 'Itlt&#039;s a nice day today', 'I went home for a rest']
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
>>> print map(h.unescape, ll)
['I went to the store', u"Itlt's a nice day today", 'I went home for a rest']
```

Comment: +1 for recommending `map()`. Though I'd probably suggest list comprehensions to a Python newbie as the OP appears to be, since their syntax looks a bit more like the `for` loop that his instinct will be pushing him to write.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change your code to this :

```
for each in regex_title:
    if 'lt&#039;' in each:
        each.replace("lt&#039;", "'")
```

**But it doesn't change your list** so you need to pass the replaced index to list:

```
>>> for each in regex_title:
...         if 'lt&#039;' in each:
...             regex_title[regex_title.index(each)]=each.replace("lt&#039;", "'")
... 
>>> regex_title
['I went to the store', "It's a nice day today", 'I went home for a rest']
>>>
```

Comment: There's a MUCH better way to do this, using list comprehensions: `new_list = [s.replace("lt&#039;", "'") for s in old_list]`. But as I said in my answer, better to use HTMLParser.

Comment: thanks for reminding i know that there is a lot ways for this aim , but at first i attempt to refine the OP's idea ! then i will add another ways !

Comment: If you need indexes, use `enumerate`. Using `list.index` inside a loop is not efficient.

Comment: i think using `enumerate` in this case decrease the performance because it need to store the index for every index in every cycle ! while we just need one index !

Comment: i see that and dont find anything ! about our topic !

Comment: `list.index` has O(n) time complexity (same for `x in list`).

Comment: yes ,exactly !but there is not any thing about comparison between `enumerate` and `list.index` i think its desire for a good benchmarking .... any way thanks for proposition

Answer (score 1):

You don't explain **why** you want to avoid importing standard library modules. There are very few good reasons to deny yourself the use of Python's included batteries; unless you have such a reason (and if you do, you should state it), you should use the functionality provided to you.

In this case, it's the [`unescape()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) function from the `html` module: <sup>1</sup>

```
from html import unescape

titles = [
    'I went to the store',
    'It&#039;s a nice day today',
    'I went home for a rest'
]

fixed = [unescape(s) for s in titles]
```

```
>>> fixed
['I went to the store', "It's a nice day today", 'I went home for a rest']
```

Reimplementing `html.unescape()` yourself is

1. Pointless.
2. Error-prone.
3. Going to mean constantly going back and adding new cases when new HTML entities crop up in your data.

---

<sup>1</sup> Since Python 3.4, anyway. For previous versions, use `HTMLParser.HTMLParser.unescape()` as per [@stalk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26174192/1014938).

Comment: It was the requirement of a project to not import other modules. I'm sure this will be useful for someone in the future though, so there you go. Cheers.

Comment: Worth to point, that this code is for python3, not for python2 (`html` module is in python3 only)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this yourself, you'd be better off using the `HTMLParser` library, as described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/2314532. Read that question and answer for all the details, but the summary is:

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
print parser.unescape('&#039;')
# Will print a single ' character
```

So in your case, you'd want to do something like:

```
import HTMLParser
parser = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
new_titles = [parser.unescape(s) for s in regex_title]
```

That will unescape *any* HTML escape, not just the `&#039;` escape that you asked about, and process the entire list all at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:-

```
 regex_title = ['I went to the store', 'Itlt&#039;s a nice day today', 'I went home for a rest']
 str=','.join(regex_title)
 str1=str.replace("lt&#039;","'");    
 print str1.split()
```