# how to decode the sample?

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

please help solve the problem.

I do parsing page:

```
....
....
<h2>Физико-механические характеристики гранита Камбулатовский</h2> 
<p/>
....
....
```

python code:

```
import lxml.etree
import lxml.html

for elt in doc.xpath('//table[@id="single-stone"]/following-sibling::div/*[position()>3]'):
    # result:
    # b'<h2>&#1060;&#1080;&#1079;&#1080;&#1082;&#1086;-&#1084;&#1077;&#1093;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1095;&#1077;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1077; &#1093;&#1072;&#1088;&#1072;&#1082;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1080;&#1089;&#1090;&#1080;&#1082;&#1080; &#1075;&#1088;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1072; &#1050;&#1072;&#1084;&#1073;&#1091;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;</h2> '
    # b'<p/>'
    stri = lxml.etree.tostring(elt)
    print(stri)
```

the result is displayed:

```
b'<h2>&#1060;&#1080;&#1079;&#1080;&#1082;&#1086;-&#1084;&#1077;&#1093;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1095;&#1077;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1077; &#1093;&#1072;&#1088;&#1072;&#1082;&#1090;&#1077;&#1088;&#1080;&#1089;&#1090;&#1080;&#1082;&#1080; &#1075;&#1088;&#1072;&#1085;&#1080;&#1090;&#1072; &#1050;&#1072;&#1084;&#1073;&#1091;&#1083;&#1072;&#1090;&#1086;&#1074;&#1089;&#1082;&#1080;&#1081;</h2> '
b'<p/>'
```

but I need to warn them on screen:

```
<h2>Физико-механические характеристики гранита Камбулатовский</h2> 
<p/>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: What about `print(eval(stri))` or `stri = lxml.etree.tounicode(elt)` ?