# python re.sub with variable

Tags: python, regex

Input text:

```
Ell &#233;s la v&#237;ctima que expia els nostres pecats, i no tan sols els nostres, sin&#243; els del m&#243;n sencer.
```

Expected output:

```
Ell és la víctima que expia els nostres pecats, i no tan sols els nostres, sinó els del món sencer.
```

Known facts:
unichr(233)=é

for now i have

```
re.sub('&#([^;]*);', r'unichr(int(\1))', inputtext, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

and of course is not working, don't know how to pass function on `\1`

Any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fortunately for you, `re.sub` accepts a function as an argument as well.  The function will recieve a ["MatchObject"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject) -- From there, you can get the matched groups by `match.group(1), match.group(2)`, etc. etc.  The return value of the function will be the string to replace the matched group in the input text.

```
def fn(match):
  return unichr(int(match.group(1)))

re.sub('&#([^;]*);', fn, inputtext, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

If you really want, you can inline this and use a lambda -- But I think lambda makes it harder to read in this case<sup>1</sup>.

---

By the way, depending on your python version, there are better ways to un-escape html (as it will also handle the special escape sequences like `'&amp;'`:

## Python2.x

```
>>> import HTMLParser
>>> s = 'Ell &#233;s la v&#237;ctima que expia els nostres pecats, i no tan sols els nostres, sin&#243; els del m&#243;n sencer.'
>>> print HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape(s)
Ell és la víctima que expia els nostres pecats, i no tan sols els nostres, sinó els del món sencer.
```

## Python3.x

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape(s)
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

<sup><sup>1</sup>especially if you give `fn` a more sensible name ;-)</sup>

Comment: will check it @mgilson, tnx for quick response

Comment: Yay for `def`, boo for `lambda`!-)

Comment: @josifoski -- I realized that it looks like you're formating HTML strings.  If so, there's a better way -- that doesn't involve regex on your part :-).  See my update.

Comment: @mgilson tnx, much better way, yes i want to make 'readable' html text

Answer (score 5):

Use a [lambda function](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#lambda):

```
re.sub('&#([^;]*);', lambda match: unichr(int(match.group(1))), t, flags=re.UNICODE)
```

Comment: This was very speedy @rawing, let me check