# Python: Replace URLEncoded characters in String with what they represent

Tags: python, url, rss

I've been banging my head against the wall with this for a while.  I'm trying to parse an RSS feed with Python's BeautifulSoup, and every now and then I get errors like:

```
I don&#39;t know what I am talking about
```

I can't seem to find any python library that will replace those characters with what they should be, so the resulting string looks like this:

```
I don't know what I am talking about
```

The closest I've gotten was

```
urllib.unquote(post_content).decode('utf-8')
```

But that still does not replace the url encoded character with a '.  Does anyone know a good way to replace those urlencoded characters into the ascii characters they represent? There's also other errors that I get like ( and ) appearing as `&#40;` and `&#41;`

Comment: This question is more suited to Stack Overflow. Programmers SE is about program design issues, not specific questions about source code.

Answer (score 0):

Those weird strings are called html entities. You can decode them as described by this URL: [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string). It says to use the function `unescape` from the module `html.parse`