# BeautifulSoup4 cannot get the printing right. Python3

Tags: python, python-3.5, beautifulsoup

I'm currently in the learning process of Python3, I am scraping a site for some data, which works fine, but when it comes to printing out the p tags I just can't get it to work as I expect.

```
import urllib
import lxml
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



data = urllib.request.urlopen('www.site.com').read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
stat = soup.find('div', {'style' : 'padding-left: 10px';})
dialog = stat.findChildren('p')

for child in dialog:
    childtext = child.get_text()
    #have tried child.string aswell (exactly the same result)
    childlist.append(childtext.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
    #Have tried with str(childtext.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))

print (childlist)
```

That all works, but the printing is "bytes"

```
b'This is a ptag.string'
b'\xc2\xa0 (probably &nbsp'
b'this is anotherone'
```

Real sample text that is ascii encoded:

```
b"Announcementb'Firefox users may encounter browser warnings encountering SSL SHA-1 certificates"
```

Note that Announcement is p and the rest is 'strong' under a p tag.

Same sample with utf-8 encode

```
b"Announcement\xc2\xa0\xe2\x80\x93\xc2\xa0b'Firefox users may encounter browser warnings encountering SSL SHA-1 "
```

I WISH to get:

```
"Announcement"
(newline / new item in list)
"Firefox users may encounter browser warnings encountering SSL SHA-1 certificates"
```

As you see, the incorrect chars are stripped in "ascii", but as some are `&nbsp;` that destroys some linebreaks and I have yet to figure out how to print that correctly, also, the b's are still there then!

I really can't figure out how to remove b's and encode or decode properly. I have tried every "solution" that I can google up.

HTML Content = utf-8

I would most rather not change the full data before processing because it will mess up my other work and I don't think it is needed.

Prettify does not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

First, you're getting output of the form `b'stuff'` because you are calling `.encode()`, which returns a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typebytes) object. If you want to print strings for reading, keep them as strings!

As a guess, I assume you're looking to print strings from HTML nicely, pretty much as they would be seen in a browser. For that, you need to decode the HTML string encoding, as described in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string), which for Python 3.5 means:

```
import html
html.unescape(childtext)
```

Among other things, this will convert any `&nbsp;` sequences in the HTML string into `'\xa0'` characters, which are printed as spaces. However, if you want to break lines on these characters despite `&nbsp;` literally meaning "non-breaking space", you'll have to replace those with actual spaces before printing, e.g. using `x.replace('\xa0', ' ')`.