# Convert HTML Entity to Python Emoji

Tags: python, html, emoji, emoticons

Say I have the following HTML emoji entity: **'&#x1f604 ;'**

Note there isn't actually a space between the 4 and the ; it's just there so that it doesn't show up as a smiley

The emoji's Python form is: **u"\U0001f604"**

**How do I convert all HTML emoji entities to their Python form?**

---

Things I have tried so far:

- Encode to utf-8
- Unescape the text using HTML Parser and then convert
- Use regex (couldn't get something that worked for all of the HTML emoji entities -- not as simple as swapping &#x with \U000 as that only works for some entities)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string

Comment: I agree that it is a duplicate. It turns out the solutions on that question did not work for me (I had looked at it before posting this) because Python 2.7.10's HTMLParser seems to be buggy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`HTMLParser.unescape` does just that:

```
In [3]: HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape( '&#x1f604;' )
Out[3]: u'\U0001f604'
```

Comment: I don't get that output for some reason

Comment: >>> import HTMLParser
>>> HTMLParser.HTMLParser().unescape( '&#x1f604;' )
>>>'&#x1f604;'

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: version Python 2.7.10

Comment: Then I don't know. The above test works with Python 2.7.6 on Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Yea, I'm not sure either. I just checked it on CoderPad, and it worked as your example.Not sure why my version of Python's acting up

Comment: Maybe it's a bug with 2.7.10. Will try to update my Python version

Comment: Just ran it on my computer's Python3 with html.unescape('&#x1f604;') and it worked. So I suspect that it's just my version of Python 2 (which I believe is the standard version of Python on a mac)

Comment: Thanks for your help!