# Decoding HTML character entities in JSON

Tags: python, json, scrapy

When I do this:

`s = response.xpath('//meta[@id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card"]').extract()`

what I get back is:

`<meta content='{"hosting":{"id":2256573,"offset_lat":39.04258923718809,"offset_lng":-95.69083697887662},"map_url":"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=%2C&amp;size&amp;zoom=14","place_recommendations":[],"neighborhood_breadcrumb_details":[{"link_text":"Southwest Fillmore Street,","search_text":"Southwest Fillmore Street Topeka, KS","link":"&lt;span&gt;Southwest Fillmore Street,&lt;/span&gt;","link_route":"/s/Southwest-Fillmore-Street-Topeka--KS"},{"link_text":"Topeka,","search_text":"Topeka, KS","link":"&lt;span&gt;Topeka,&lt;/span&gt;","link_route":"/s/Topeka--KS"},{"link_text":"Kansas,","search_text":"Kansas, United States","link":"&lt;span&gt;Kansas,&lt;/span&gt;","link_route":"/s/Kansas--United-States"},{"link_text":"United States","search_text":"United States","link":"&lt;span&gt;United States&lt;/span&gt;","link_route":"/s/United-States"}],"neighborhood_basic_info":null,"neighborhood_localized_name":null,"user_info":{"user_image":"&lt;img alt=\"Elizabeth\" data-pin-nopin=\"true\" height=\"90\" src=\"https://a0.muscache.com/im/users/9199018/profile_pic/1380782460/original.jpg?aki_policy=profile_x_medium\" title=\"Elizabeth\" width=\"90\" /&gt;"}}' id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card">`

Which is clearly JSON but it's encoded (as you can see). I tried `urllib.unquote` but that throws an error. `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'`

I was hoping to not have to resort to using a regex to do the URL decoding. What can I do (besides using a regex) to make this valid JSON?

Comment: That's not URL encoded.  URL encoding look like `This%20is%20a%20test`.  What you have there is HTML using HTML character entities like `&lt;` for `<`.  And there are already lots of good answers on how to deal with that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: Did you try `eval('('+String+')')`? Those are HTML Entities. Your problem is that is a String. You need to make it into code.

Comment: @larsks you are right, I reworded the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode using `json.loads()`, however, you need to get at the JSON string contained in the `content` attribute of `<meta>` tag.

You can make multiple calls to `xpath()` to drill into the attributes of the selected tag:

```
meta = response.xpath('//meta[@id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card"]')
content = meta.xpath('@content').extract_first()
data = json.loads(content)
```

Or you can do it in one go:

```
content = response.xpath('//meta[@id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card"]').xpath('@content').extract_first()
data = json.loads(content)
from pprint import pprint
pprint(data)
```

**Output**

```
{u'hosting': {u'id': 2256573,
              u'offset_lat': 39.04258923718809,
              u'offset_lng': -95.69083697887662},
 u'map_url': u'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?markers=%2C&size&zoom=14',
 u'neighborhood_basic_info': None,
 u'neighborhood_breadcrumb_details': [{u'link': u'Southwest Fillmore Street,',
                                       u'link_route': u'/s/Southwest-Fillmore-Street-Topeka--KS',
                                       u'link_text': u'Southwest Fillmore Street,',
                                       u'search_text': u'Southwest Fillmore Street Topeka, KS'},
                                      {u'link': u'Topeka,',
                                       u'link_route': u'/s/Topeka--KS',
                                       u'link_text': u'Topeka,',
                                       u'search_text': u'Topeka, KS'},
                                      {u'link': u'Kansas,',
                                       u'link_route': u'/s/Kansas--United-States',
                                       u'link_text': u'Kansas,',
                                       u'search_text': u'Kansas, United States'},
                                      {u'link': u'United States',
                                       u'link_route': u'/s/United-States',
                                       u'link_text': u'United States',
                                       u'search_text': u'United States'}],
 u'neighborhood_localized_name': None,
 u'place_recommendations': [],
 u'user_info': {u'user_image': u''}}
```

Comment: Unrelated, but what is the difference between print and pprint? (relative newbie here)

Comment: `pprint` == "pretty print". For nested data structures `pprint` produces a more readable output than `print`.

Comment: @Jeroen: thanks for accepting this answer, although I do think that alecxe's single xpath query is more concise: `content = response.xpath('//meta[@id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card"]/@content').extract_first()`.

Comment: yeah it is more concise, I agree, but beyond that, it's essentially the same so I looked at you guys's reputation score and yours is lower... :-)

Comment: @Jeroen: I'm grateful but that's not a reason to accept an answer. You should choose the one that best answers your question. If that's mine then great. Your selection may also affect future readers that might have a similar problem. On that basis I'm inclined to update the second part of my answer to be the same as alecxe's.

Comment: Actually @mhawke, another reason was that your answer is more verbose. As seasoned secs we may select the more concise code, for future readers yours  explains what is happening slightly better. At least IMHO...

Comment: @Jeroen: OK then. alecxe's answer is mentioned in the comments, so I suppose that's OK. Thanks.

Comment: Secs = devs... Stupid iPhone!

Answer (score 2):

Get the value of the `content` attribute and load it via `json.loads()`:

```
>>> import json
>>> content = response.xpath('//meta[@id="_bootstrap-neighborhood_card"]/@content').extract_first()
>>> json.loads(content)
```

Note that you also need to use `extract_first()` instead of `extract()` to get a string value and not a list.