# python3.4 How to decode string to what I want

Tags: python-3.4, decode

I get some string from web use python3.4.
Here is string I get:

```
str="&#60lily&#62"
```

How to get this result?

```
str="<lily>"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use replace:

```
str="&#60lily&#62"
str.replace("&#60","<").replace("&#62",">")
```

Comment: @E.Tarrent if you want decode html entities see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string

Comment: Thank you.This is what I want