# Decode HTML string using python 2.7

Tags: python, html, python-2.7, decode, pretty-print

I want the following HTML string to be decoded with HTML tags

```
\u003cp\u003e\u003cstrong\u003e\u003cspan\u003eAbout the Company \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/p\u003e
```

How can I do that in Python 2.7 ?

I am having large HTML string to decode. The above sample is just a apart of that.

PS: I have tried with many solutions available in web to decode HTML string but nothing helps me **EDIT:**
I have referred this https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/4350834
and got the result as

```
\u003cp\u003e\u003cstrong\u003e\u003cspan\u003eAbout the Company \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/p\u003e
```

Comment: *"I have tried with many solutions available in web to decode HTML string but nothing helps me"* - so where's the [mcve]?

Comment: And **what happened** when you *"referred"* that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>>text = "\u003cp\u003e\u003cstrong\u003e\u003cspan\u003eAbout the Company \u003c/span\u003e\u003c/strong\u003e\u003c/p\u003e".decode('unicode-escape')
>>>print text
u'<p><strong><span>About the Company </span></strong></p>'
```

Comment: This works for me