# Reading CSV files with python (pandas) when there is HTML escaped string in there

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pandas

I'm trying to read a CSV file with pandas read_csv. The data looks like this (example)

```
thing;weight;price;colour
apple;1;2;red
m &amp; m's;0;10;several
cherry;0,5;2;dark red
```

Because of the HTML-escaped ampersand thingy, the second row would contain 5 fields according to pandas. How can I make sure, that thing gets read correctly?

The example here is pretty much how my data looks like: separator is ";", no string quotes, cp1251 encoding.
The data I receive is pretty big, and reading it must run in one step (meaning no preprocessing outside of python).

I didn't find any reference in the pandas doc (I'm using pandas 0.19 with python 3.5.1). Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Comment: is the &amp always on the first column, and is it something that you would want to remove from the dataset entirely?

Comment: No, the &amp; (and &gt; and &lt; and &auml; things) are all around the place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Unescape the html character references](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2087370/190597):

```
import html
with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f, open('data-fixed.csv', 'w') as g:
    content = html.unescape(f.read())
    g.write(content)
print(content)
# thing;weight;price;colour
# apple;1;2;red
# m & m's;0;10;several
# cherry;0,5;2;dark red
```

Then load the csv in the usual way:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('data-fixed.csv', sep=';')
print(df)
```

yields

```
     thing weight  price    colour
0    apple      1      2       red
1  m & m's      0     10   several
2   cherry    0,5      2  dark red
```

---

Although the data file is "pretty big", you appear to have enough memory to read it into a DataFrame. Therefore you should also have enough memory to read the file into a single string: `f.read()`. Converting the HTML with one call to `html.unescape` is more performant than calling `html.unescape` on many smaller strings. This is why I suggest using

```
with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f, open('data-fixed.csv', 'w') as g:
    content = html.unescape(f.read())
    g.write(content)
```

instead of something like

```
with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f, open('data-fixed.csv', 'w') as g:
    for line in f:
        g.write(html.unescape(line))
```

---

If you need to read this data file more than once, then it pays to fix it (and save it
to disk) so you don't need to call `html.unescape` every time you wish to parse
the data. That's why I suggest writing the unescaped contents to `data-fixed.csv`.

If reading this data is a one-off task and you wish to avoid the performance or resource cost of writing to disk, then you could use a StringIO (in-memory file-like object):

```
from io import StringIO
import html
import pandas as pd

with open('data.csv', 'r', encoding='cp1251') as f:
    content = html.unescape(f.read())
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep=';')
print(df)
```

Comment: Would `df = pd.read_csv(content, sep=';')` work without writing the (possibly large) file?

Comment: @IanS: You would need to wrap `content` in a StringIO:  `from io import StringIO`,  `df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(content), sep=';')`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a regex as separator for `pandas.read_csv`
In your specific case you can try:

```
pd.read_csv("test.csv",sep = "(?<!&amp);")
#         thing weight  price    colour
#0        apple      1      2       red
#1  m &amp; m's      0     10   several
#2       cherry    0,5      2  dark red
```

to select all the `;` not preceded by `&amp`, this can be extended to other escaped characters

Comment: If I try to modify this by using `sep = "(?<!&[a-z]*);"` then I get an error. But liked the idea...