# Pandas read_csv() with HTML special characters

Tags: python, html, pandas, csv

I am cleaning up a CSV file in Python/Pandas, comma delimited.

Some of the cells have `&amp;` as part of the text. When I run read_csv(), it is seeing that semicolon as the end of the current cell and offsetting the rest of the row.

I've tried `encoding='utf8'` and various other options...

EDIT**
My code:

```
file = pd.read_csv('my-data-1.csv', encoding = 'utf8',index_col=False, low_memory=False)

file.drop(file.tail(1).index,inplace=True) #removing copyright line at the end


file_drop_dupes = file.drop_duplicates(['Project Id']) #drop the duplicates based on column Project Id

#drop all columns except these few
keep_col = ['Project Id','Project Name', 'Type']
new_file = file_drop_dupes[keep_col]
#write the result to a new csv file
new_file.to_csv('all-good-1.csv', index=False)
```

an example of field with HTML:

```
Service Maintenance &amp; Supply
```

Comment: Can you post an example and some code? I don't see this issue in my little test using pd.read_csv()

Comment: Just added more context thx

Comment: And when you say that the rest of the row is offset, are you saying that Pandas is interpreting the semi-colon as the end of the field? If I create a df with that example field in, I can read it fine. Sorry I can't seem to help.

Comment: Yes, pandas is using the semicolon as the end of that field and starting a new field. So on rows that contain the HTML character (maybe 10%), there ends up being an extra column at the end.

Comment: I don't see the problem on my test but it looks like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399640/reading-csv-files-with-python-pandas-when-there-is-html-escaped-string-in-ther) might help you:

Answer (score 0):

In python 3.4+, it's a simple `html.unescape()`. Before that, html.parser's `HTMLParser.unescape()`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/314922).

Comment: Can you explain how I'd integrate that? I tried something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40399640/reading-csv-files-with-python-pandas-when-there-is-html-escaped-string-in-ther

However I get an error:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u200e'

Comment: I am in Python 3.5 btw

Answer (score 0):

If you are using python 3+ `html.unescape()` is the solution