# Get row data from a table using Beautifilsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm Using Beautifulsoup to turn the data in this table to a json. 
However, how do I get the data between the tags?

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Montag</th>
    <td>
     09:00 &ndash; 00:30
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Dienstag</th>
  <td>
   geschlossen
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Mittwoch</th>
  <td>
  12:00 &ndash; 00:30
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Donnerstag &ndash; Sonntag</th>
  <td>
    09:00 &ndash; 00:30
  </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Unfortunately, this is not working:

```
datesTable = BeautifulSoup(mytable)

for row in datesTable: 
   print(row['th'])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) on how to decode the escaped HTML strings according to your version of python.

```
table = """
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Montag</th>
    <td>
     09:00 &ndash; 00:30
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Dienstag</th>
  <td>
   geschlossen
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Mittwoch</th>
  <td>
  12:00 &ndash; 00:30
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <th>Donnerstag &ndash; Sonntag</th>
  <td>
    09:00 &ndash; 00:30
  </td>
</tr>
</table>"""

import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(table, 'html5lib')

data = {}

for row in soup.findAll('tr'):
    th = row.find('th')
    td = row.find('td')
    data[th.text.strip()] = td.text.strip()

print(json.dumps(data))
```

Comment: Note: you are using the `BeautifulSoup` version 3 which is very outdated and not maintained.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account your actual problem statement of converting an HTML to JSON, you can use [`pandas.read_html()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html) to read HTML into a `DataFrame` and then convert it to a dictionary:

```
import pandas as pd

data = """
your HTML abbreviated to save space
"""

df = pd.read_html(data)[0]
df.columns = ["label", "value"]
print(dict(zip(df.label, df.value)))
```

Prints:

```
{'Montag': '09:00 – 00:30', 
 'Dienstag': 'geschlossen', 
 'Mittwoch': '12:00 – 00:30', 
 'Donnerstag – Sonntag': '09:00 – 00:30'}
```

You can then use [`json.dumps()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps) to further dump the dictionary into a JSON string.

There is also [`.to_json()` method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_json.html) that can directly dump a `DataFrame` to `JSON`, but I have not figured out how to use it in this particular case.

Comment: Even though pandas will probably do the job, it is a bit too much for such a simple task, and I'm using Beautifulsoup already in this project (to find the table in a html file).  thanks anyway.

Comment: @lxer sure, no problem, it's just another instrument to solve the problem.