# Splitting on a lookahead

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to split on a lookahead, but it doesn't work for the last occurrence. How do I do this?

```
my_str = 'HRC&#226;&#128;&#153;s'
import re
print(re.split(r'.(?=&)', my_str))
```

My output:

```
['HR', '&#226', '&#128', '&#153;s']
```

My desired output:

```
['HRC', '&#226', '&#128', '&#153', 's']
```

Comment: Hint: It has something to do with `.`...

Comment: The input (which contains no colons) does not match the stated output (which has a colon in the last item).

Comment: @JackManey I did remove `.` but still same

Comment: Why would you expect `'...&#153;s'` to split into `[... '&#153', 's']`

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I changed that manually because if I leave as `;` string converts to ascii character

Comment: @AJNeufeld Because I will convert each `&#153` to ascii character

Comment: Irrelevant...why would you expect that split to change `&#153;s` into `[&#153, s]`? Either it's your expected output after the call to `re.split` or it isn't.

Comment: And for that matter, there are no (visible) characters between `HRC` and `&#226` in your string above. I'm not sure what you think you're trying to accomplish with any kind of split, here...

Comment: @JackManey After i split each characters to `&#226` etc. I will get rid of `&#` then use `chr(226)` to get ascii chr.

Comment: If all you want to do is decode HTML entities, you should do that instead of messing with regex. See the linked duplicate.

Comment: @MahmutKilic I'm not sure if you know what it means to `split` a string into a list of strings. When you perform a `split`, the delimiter (or resulting match from a delimiter pattern, in the case of `re.split`) **does not show up in any of the elements in the resulting list of strings**. Why would you expect `'HRC&#226'` to split into `['HRC', '&#226']`???

Comment: @JackManey What will be your suggestion for me then? I am kinda struggling how to solve this issue.

Comment: @MahmutKilic Don't `split`. If you want to decode HTML entities, then just decode them.

Comment: @JackManey http://paste.ubuntu.com/23962832/ Take a look at this. This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: i do not know how to specifically pick each `&#226` from text file

Comment: Well, are the things you're trying to decode always of the form `&#` followed by digits?

Comment: Actually, scratch that, **just decode the damn HTML entities**. Looked at the linked duplicate to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @JackManey Thank you i will take look at the link now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution using [**re.findall()**](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.findall) function:

```
my_str = 'HRC&#226;&#128;&#153;s'
result = re.findall(r'\w+|&#\d+(?=;)', my_str)
print(result)
```

The output:

```
['HRC', '&#226', '&#128', '&#153', 's']
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works great!!

Comment: @MahmutKilic, you're welcome

Comment: An alternative: `result = re.sub(r"&#(\d+);", lambda m: chr(int(m.group(1))), my_str)`