# How to handle HTML entities in parsed text - Python

Tags: python, html

I have a parsed text what contains HTML versions of different symbols like quotation marks or dashes.

This is how one string looks like:

> ```
> Introduction &#8211 First page&#8218s content
> ```

And I would like to achive this:

> ```
> Introduction - First page's content
> ```

Is there any library or common solution that changes the HTML entities in any string? Or I would need to write a function which replace the html to the proper string?

I already checked [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string), but I would rather need something that works with a simple Python string that contains html entities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`html` module doesn't require anything special from the string. It just works:

```
>>> import html
>>> html.unescape('Introduction &#8211 First page&#8218s content')
'Introduction – First page‚s content'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print unicode(x)
```

or

`print x.encode('ascii')`