# Replace HTML-special-character-codes in Python3

Tags: html, python-3.x

I recieve HTML-files and they contain Strings like that `&quot;` ("), `&#252;`(ü) and so on.

I need them humand-readable. So I could use `str.replace()` for that. But isn't there a package/library for Python3 which knows all character-codes by itself and could handle that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `html.unescape()`:

```
import html
print(html.unescape('&quot;&#252;'))
```

Answer (score 1):

Se the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string). It's called decode (or unescape)  and yes there is a library for that.

Comment: No links without explanations please.

Comment: Someone asked almost the same question as you. You can find the explanation there.

Comment: In that case you could __flag__ the queston as a duplicate. I did this for my self now. ;)