# Decoding &quot; for images and links in Django

Tags: html, django, postgresql, ckeditor

For a Django application I am writing, I am using a Postgres database and storing CKEditor output in said database.

Links are stored as follows: `<a href=&quot;http://google.com&quot;>google</a>`

Images are stored as follows: `<img src=&quot;https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D&quot; />`

In the template, I output this html along with the rest of the stored content from the database using the safe tag: `{{post.content |safe}}`

Chrome sees href and src without " marks and adds them in around the `&quot;`, leading to `href=""http://google.com""` which causes all kinds of problems.

Any thoughts on how to fix this problem? Do I need to mess with CKEditor to store unescaped quotation marks? Should I add a template tag or javascript function to replace all of these encoded quotation marks?

Comment: use a template tag

Comment: should I replace the "safe" tag? It's rendering a big block of content. I'm not sure how to apply a tag just to the links and images and i'm not sure I want to unescape all &quot;.

Comment: if these links resides in the block of data and you don't want to escape all the characters then i would suggest that you use regex to replace the desired quotes

Comment: @ApritSolanki Do not use regex to parse html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue using a template tag as Arpit suggested.

```
## app/templatetags/unescape_quotes.py ##

from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def unescape_quotes(s):
    html_codes = (
            ('"', '&quot;'),
        )
    for code in html_codes:
        s = s.replace(code[1], code[0])
    return s
```

In the template:

```
{% load unescape_quotes %}
{{post.content |unescape_quotes |safe }}
```

It's just an s.replace but written so that I can unescape more html later if I'd like just by adding the codes.

Answer (score 0):

Do not store entities in the first place. Put `'entities': False,` in your CKEditor config.

Now all your new data will be stored correctly. To fix the old data you should write a data migration. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/migrations/#data-migrations

Create an empty migration with `python manage.py makemigrations --empty appname`. And use `migrations.RunPython(your_data_migration)` to process the data.

The function could contain a simple `replace('&quote', '"')` OR use an HTMLParser like shown in this SO-answer: [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string#2087433)

Comment: It's better practice to store unsafe HTML in the database and let the template deal with it?

Comment: Yes, If you worry about unsafe html you should white list your html tags and attributes. Sanitise the input. Encoded html is not save html. I believe storing clean data is the way to go.