# How to decode ascii combined with string in python

Tags: python, ascii, decode

I am trying to decode and ascii which is combined with string

example

```
g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104
```

But i am not getting exact output

```
'g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104'.decode("ascii")
```

output

```
u'g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104'
```

if u remove this characters &# and try only with integers i get this

```
>>> chr(108)
'l'
>>> chr(115)
's'
>>> chr(111)
'o'
>>> chr(114)
'r'
>>> chr(104)
'h'
```

expected output

```
glbosworth
```

How can i decode this one "g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104" to expected output

Comment: Looks kind of like a string with weird randomly escaped HTML entities `html.unescape('g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104')` returns `'glbosworth'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- on python3.6.x you can use [html.unescape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape):

  ```
  import html
  print(html.unescape('g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104'))
  ```
- on python 2.x you can use [HTMLParser](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html):

  ```
  from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
  h = HTMLParser()
  print(h.unescape('g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104'))
  ```

Comment: python 2.x is not working i get this result g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to decode [html escaped string](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp). you can use the [`html.unescape(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.html#html.unescape) function to do so (on python3):

```
import html
print(html.unescape('g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104'))
```

outputs:

```
'glbosworth'
```

take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2087433/7438048) so answer for more info

Comment: any options for python 2.7

Comment: i tried this from HTMLParser import HTMLParser
h = HTMLParser()
print(h.unescape('g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104')) but getting different results "g&#108bo&#115w&#111&#114t&#104
"

Comment: you can try bs4