# python 3 Decode string sta&#195;&#159;e

Tags: python, python-3.x

how can I decode a string containing stuff like this:

```
sta&#195;&#159;e
```

to

```
staße
```

using python.

(EDIT: Interpreting the source as html entities does not lead to the desired result, but "staÃe")

Background: I am struggling to work with the amazon mws response-strings using the [mws client](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mws) you get when doing `pip install mws`. Especially wondering because the sourcestring looks like it contains 2 special characters, but the goal is just 'ß'.

[In the docs](http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_US/dev_guide/DG_ResponseFormat.html) they are talking about a Unicode character limit i did not understand

Comment: Tried [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) but doesn't do the job.

Comment: Was my first idea as well, but interpreting the escaped characters as html entities (as in your linked thread) leads to "staÃe". I tried that at http://www.convertstring.com/de/EncodeDecode/HtmlDecode

Comment: yeah, just saw that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the problem here is that `ß` is represented in UTF-8 as the sequence of two bytes: C3 9F hex or 195 159 decimal. However, as you decode your entities as HTML, they end up as Unicode **code points** 195 and 159, 195 being code point for Ã. You will have to do some voodoo, like casting the `str` to `bytes` and then decoding `bytes` to (Unicode) `str`. Compare the results of:

```
print('\xc3\x9f')

print(bytes('\xc3\x9f', 'Latin-1').decode())
```

Comment: thanks, your snippet in combination with setting utf-8 as encoding on the output xml file solved the problem