# JSON.parse() returns a string instead of object

Tags: javascript, json

I'd hate to open a new question even though many questions have been opened on this same topic, but I'm literally at my ends as to why this isn't working.

I am attempting to create a JSON object with the following code:

```
                var p = JSON.stringify(decodeJSON('{{post.as_json}}'))
                var post = JSON.parse(p);
                console.log(post); // Debug log to test if code is valid
```

And the `decodeJSON` function:

```
    function decodeJSON(json) {
        var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
        txt.innerHTML = json;
        return txt.value.replace(/u'/g, "'");
        }
```

`console.log(post)` returns the following JSON string:

```
{'content': 'kj fasf', 'uid': '4eL1BQ__', 'created': '07/09/2017', 'replies': [], 'tags': ['python'], 'by': {'username': 'Dorian', 'img_url': '/static/imgs/user_Dorian/beaut.jpg'}, 'likes': 0}
```

After scanning through the string I am pretty sure that the JSON is valid and there are no syntax errors. However, when running `JSON.parse(p)` Instead of receiving an object, I get a string back. What could be the cause?

Comment: That's not a JSON string. JSON uses `"`, not `'`

Comment: @baao I thought that could be the cause as well. So I tried replacing all of the `'` with `"`, but I then get an `Invalid token` error.

Comment: It seems like you are using a templating engine. If yes, all you have to do is `var post = {{post.as_json}};` and call it a day. However, that assumes that `as_json` really returns JSON which doesn’t seem to be the case. You should fix that first. Everything else is just a hacky workaround.

Comment: It returns extra HTML symbols like `&#39;` which I use the `decodeJSON` post to remove.

Comment: Why don't you decode HTML entities on the server? I assume you are using Python: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string .

Answer (score 2):

That's because `decodeJSON` returns a string, and `JSON.stringify` turns that **string** in **another** **string**.

In the other hand, you used `JSON.strigify()` method on a string. You should stringify an **object**, not **string**.

> JSON.stringify() turns a javascript object to json text and stores it
>   in a string.

When you use `JSON.parse` you obtain the **string** returned by `decodedJSON` function, not object.

Solution:

```
var p = JSON.stringify('{{post.as_json}}');
var post = JSON.parse(p);
console.log(post);
```

> It gives me Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at
>   position 1

The solution is to modify your `decodeJSON` method.

```
function decodeJSON(json) {
    var txt = document.createElement("textarea");
    txt.innerHTML = json;
    return txt.value.replace(/u'/g, '\"');
}

var p = decodeJSON('{{post.as_json}}');
var post = JSON.parse(p);
console.log(post);
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your code is that you are performing `JSON.stringify` on a string itself. So on parsing the result of this string will be a string. In effect, you have stringified twice and parsed once. If you parse it once more you will get a JSON. But for solution avoid the stringification twice.

Replace in your code.

```
var p = decodeJSON('{{post.as_json}}');
```

That will work

Comment: It gives me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' in JSON at position 1`