# decode html entities to chinese characters

Tags: html, linux, shell, locale

need help
My curl output shows chinese characters as (on Linux terminal)

```
&#44592;&#53440;/&#48512;&#51116;&#49884; &#51665; &#50526;&#50640; &#45459;&#44256;&#44032;&#49492;&#46104
```

1. I need the output in chinese characters like (기타/부재시 집 앞에 놓고가셔되)
   OR-OR-oR
2. how to convert these html to entities to chinese characters on terminal 
   Please note I do not have php installed on my machine. so I can not use html_entity_decode or other php decode methods

I have perl and python installed on my machine.

Comment: showing as 
&#48512;&#51116;&#49884; &#51665; &#50526;&#50640; &#45459;&#44256;&#44032;&#49492;&#46104; &#46121

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Answer (score 0):

Just pipe the output through this simple Perl substitution:

```
perl -CO -pe 's/&#(\d+);/chr $1/ge'
```

- `-p` reads the input line by line and prints each after processing
- `-CO` turns on UTF-8 encoding of the output
- `/e` evaluates the replacement part of the `s///` substitution as code
- [chr](http://p3rl.org/chr) just returns the character of the given number in the character set.

Comment: Thanks for answer, it's almost working, it still showing with semicolons, how can I remove these semicolons as below without using sed comand
기;타;/부;재;시; 집; 앞;에; 놓;고;가;셔;되; 됩;니;다;/박;태;현;
it should be like 기타/부재시 집 앞에 놓고가셔되 됩니다/박태현

Comment: Oh sorry, just include the semicolon in the replacement part. Edited.