# Python Beautifulsoup extract hexadecimal values

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am building a scraper where I want to extract the data from some tags as it is without any conversion. But Beautifulsoup changing some hex values to ASCII. For example, this code gets converted into ASCII

```
html = """\
<title>&#x42;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x20;&#x61;&#x64;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;&#x73;&#x73; - &#x50;&#x61;&#x79;&#x50;&#x61;&#x6C;</title>
<title>Billing address - PayPal</title>"""
```

Here's the small example of the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
for element in soup.findAll(['title', 'form', 'a']):
    print(str(element))
```

But I want to extract the data in the same form. I believe BeautifulSoup 4 auto converting HTML entities and this is what I don't want. Any help would be really appreciated.

BTW I am using Python 3.5 and Beautifulsoup 4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string)

Comment: BeautifulSoup 4 auto converting HTML entities and this is what I don't want.

Answer (score 1):

you might try using `re` module ( [Regular Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) ). for an instance the code below will extract the title tag info without converting it: (I assumed that you declared html variable before)

```
import re
result = re.search('\<title\>.*\<\/title\>',html).group(0)
print(result) # It'll print <title>&#x42;&#x69;&#x6C;&#x6C;&#x69;&#x6E;&#x67;&#x20;&#x61;&#x64;&#x64;&#x72;&#x65;&#x73;&#x73; - &#x50;&#x61;&#x79;&#x50;&#x61;&#x6C;</title>
```

You may do the same for the other tags as well

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, But I want to achieve this with BeautifulSoup only. Its because there are multiple other tags from which I am fetching the values and might possible they have the same hex strings.