# How to convert this text to these words using python?

Tags: python

I used python to get html page from a japanese comic site, and used regex to only extract some titles of chapters of the comics. I can get most of them correctly as it is but some of them comes in different formats.

An example is here `&#39608;&#39592;&#39438;&#22763;&#27096;&#12289;&#21482;&#20170;&#30064;&#19990;&#30028;&#12408;&#12362;&#20986;&#25499;&#12369;&#20013;_&#31532;19&#31456;`

I thought i'll try to check for similar questions about this type of format but when I type this in google it's automatically converted to japanese words.

Sorry if this might be an obvious question to some of you, but I have no idea how to convert this using python. Please help me convert this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "&#39608;&#39592;&#39438;&#22763;&#27096;&#12289;&#21482;&#20170;&#30064;&#19990;&#30028;&#12408;&#12362;&#20986;&#25499;&#12369;&#20013;_&#31532;19&#31456;"
import html
print(html.unescape(str))
```

See [Decode HTML entities in Python string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2087370/decode-html-entities-in-python-string) for more details.